# How to map a database query into an Object [in Java]?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a query that joins 5 tables.
Then I fill my hand-made object with the column values that I need.

What are solutions here that are wide-common to solve that problem using specific tools ? are there such tools?

I'm only beginning to learn Hibernate, so my question would be: is Hibernate the right decision for this problem?

Hibernate maps a table to a class. So, there's no difference if I would have 5 classes instead of 5 tables. It would still be difficult to join the query result into a class

**Could hibernate be used to map THE QUERY into the structure (class) I would define beforehand as we do with table mapping? Or even better, can it map the query result into the meaningful fields [auto-create the class with fields] as it does with reverse-engineering?**

*I've been thinking about views but.. create a new view everytime we need a complex query.. too verbose.*

As S.Lott asked, here is a simple version of a question:

General problem:

```
select A.field_a, B.field_b, C.field_c 
 from table_a A inner join table_b B inner join table_c C 
 where ...
```

every table contains 100 fields
query returns 3 fields, but every field belongs to the unique table

How do I solve that problem in an OO style?
Design a new object with properties corresponding to the returning values of the query.

I want to know if it is the right [and the only one possible] decision and are there any common solutions.

See also my comments.

Comment: -1: The title of this question is uselessly vague.  Please update the title to reflect that you *really* want to know.  "mapping" is too simplistic.  This question is deeper than that.

Comment: I want to know how it is generally made, not only in my particular case. ORM may not be the real case here, I mentioned Hibernate because I suspect that IT CAN BE USED in such a situation. But it can be made by hand as well. ORM praises the concept of 1:1 relationship between the table and the class [with minor differences, probably, as field names & number of fields]. It may be used in my case, but should it?

Comment: @EugeneP:  Do not ask us to read your comments.  Update your question.  Questions last forever, lots and lots of people will read the question.  Please take the time to get the question RIGHT.  Absolutely RIGHT.  If you have to close it to try again, that's good.  Your comments, however, will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The point of ORM is to Map Objects to Relations.

The point of ORM is -- explicitly -- *not* to sweat the details of a specific SQL join.

One fundamental guideline to understanding ORM is this.

**SQL joins are a hack because SQL doesn't have proper navigation.**

To do ORM design, we to intentionally set the SQL join considerations aside as (largely) irrelevant.  Give up the old ways.  It's okay, really.  The SQL crutches aren't supporting us very well.

Step 1.  Define the domain of discourse.  The real-world objects.

Step 2.  Define implementation classes that are a high-fidelity model of real-world things.

Step 3.  Map the objects to relations.  Here's where the hack-arounds start.  SQL doesn't have a variety of collections -- it only has tables.  SQL doesn't have subclasses, it only has tables.  So you have to design a "good-enough" mapping between object classes and tables.  Ideally, this is one-to-one.  But in reality, it doesn't work out that way.  Often you will have some denormalization to handle class hierarchies.  Other than that, it should work out reasonably well.

Yes you have to add many-to-many association tables that have no object mapping.

Step 4.  You're done.  Write your application.

"But what about my query that joins 5 (or 3) tables but only takes one attribute from each table?"

What about it?  One of those tables is the real object you're dealing with.  The other of those 5 (or 3) tables are either part of 1-m nested collections, m-1 containers or m-m associations.  That's just navigation among objects.

A 1-m nested collection is the kind of thing that SQL treats as a "result set".  In ORM it will become a proper object collection.

A m-1 contain is the typical FK relationship.  In ORM it's just a fetch of a related object through ordinary object navigation.

A m-m association is also an object collection.  It's a strange collection because two objects are members of each other's collections, but it's just an object collection.

At no time do you design an object that matches a query.  You design an object that matches the real world, map that to the database.

"What about performance?"  It's only a problem when you subvert the ORM's simple mapping rules.  Once in a blue moon you have to create a special-purpose view to handle really big batch-oriented joins among objects.  But this is really rare.  Often, rethinking your Java program's navigation patterns will improve performance.

Remember, ORM's cache your results.  Each "navigation" may not be a complete "round-trip" to the database query.  Some queries may be batched by the ORM for you.

Comment: I got a schema like that: SomeOtherUserPropsTable <- User (main details: name etc) -> Service_User -> Service (what user can make use of)

Already 4 tables. Very common if we need all that info at once.

Comment: >>"5-table join is not -- and should not be -- a single class"<< What if that class would contain other objects that are subproperties ?

Comment: Then those subproperties should be different classes; e.g. in the above case, a `ServiceUser` is a subclass of `User` and contains an otherprops `Map` and a reference to a `Service` instance etc.  A single class itself should typically be defined in a single table, even though you may need to look up multiple tables to fully populate its dependencies.

Comment: @EugeneP: Please update the question with additional information.

Comment: @Andrzej. Yes references. The main class here would be User. Other properties may present or not present, and if needed, they would be of complex type like Map. They ARE different classes. But they all present a complex instance, ie the Class [User] that represent my 5-joins-query.

Comment: The situtation is a bit tricky, though. Speaking of design, right. you could map a table into a class and query each table and get multiple classes that are joined by reference. But if you exactly that you'll need only one Service per one User and you need only these 3 properties, why map everything into a Map? You can make a helper class that models THIS SITUATION. You'll need this,that and that other field only. You don't want all data to be populated!

Comment: @EugeneP: You're missing the point.  "optional" things are not part of  a JOIN.  They're part of an "OUTER JOIN" in SQL.  They are represented as "navigation" in the ORM.  Sometimes you'll fetch these other objects, other times you'll find that they don't exist and are `null`.  You should search for "ORM design" and perhaps open a new question on design.

Comment: @Lott:
Optional means "now". When I need a surname, I would not query for name. Talking about User<-AdditionalPropsOfUser (two tables). If I do not need those additional properties, I would not even join those two tables! YOu see? Then, again. Say, I have 10 services attached to a user (User->Service_User<-Service). If I know the service id, I WILL INNER JOIN the two tables, but I will have a WHERE clause. So I'll get a reference to a needed service. OK. Now, suppose I need to know only 1 field of the Service row. Why not use a String field instead of a Service object?

Comment: Generally speaking, my table user_table may have 100 properties: surname, name, salary, dateOfBirth etc. I know that in this particular project I will only need 3 fields. Why cannot I make a class with 3 fields only? This simple explanation can be generalized to the above question. A query joins tables with tons of info. But it extracts only 5 fields. Why not make a Class with 5 fields and populate it with the query result? Simple? Little memory consumption? Concrete? Why do we need all that overhead as in Hibernate?

Comment: @EugeneP: Simple.  The point is simple.  Object Class == Table == Simple == High Fidelity Model of Reality.

Comment: Hmm. Gotta thing about it. Even after my explanation you insist that 1:1 mapping is always better because it better describes the domain model? Hmm. Where's the simplicity, the KISS principle?

Comment: @EugeneP: That is the KISS principle.  A SQL Query is a hack-around because of the limitations of the relational model.  A SQL Query is not a first-class part of the problem.  It's one alternative implementation -- and not a very good one.  That's why we use ORM.  To get away from SQL Queries as having any "meaning".  They're just implementation in a not-very-good language.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. Create a single table mapping using `<join>` elements for the related tables.  A join in that way will allow other tables to contribute properties to your class.
2. Use a database view as previously suggested.
3. Use a Hibernate mapping view - instead of `<class name=... table=...` you can use `<class name=... select="select A.field_a, B.field_b, ... from A, B, ...">`.  It's essentially creating a view on the Hibernate side so the database doesn't have to change.  The generated sql will end up looking like "`select * from (select A.field_a, B.field_b from A, B, ...)`
   ".  I know that works in Oracle, DB2, and MySQL

All that is fine for selecting; if you need to do insert/update, you'll probably need to rethink your data model or your object model.

Comment: Only SELECTING - THAT IS THE POINT in my case.

Comment: +1. First option is the best if there are no complex join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you could use the Criteria API in Hibernate to map the results of your join into your target class.