# How to map join query to non-entity class in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In hibernate

Join queries can be mapped with non-entity class . [How to map a database query into an Object [in Java]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873316/how-to-map-a-database-query-into-an-object-in-java/1874777#1874777)

```
<class name=... select="select A.field_a, B.field_b, ... from A, B, ...">
```

How can I achieve the same thing in JPA/Hibernate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In hibernate you can invoke a constructor of any arbitrary class inside the select clause of a query.

```
@NamedQuery( name = "myScalarQuery" query =
"select new org.stackoverflow.hibernate.QueryResultObject(A.field_a, B.field_b) 
  from A, B
  where a.someUsefulProperty = b.someComparableProperty")
```

etc.  (note fully qualified classname is required)

Then you just need the class the has a matching constructor

```
public class QueryResultObject {

public QueryResultObject(TypeOfFieldA fieldA, TypeOfFieldB fieldB) {
//etc
}

}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this [constructor expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbw) is a feature of JPA generally (going back to Java EE 5 when JPA was split out from the EJB spec). You don't *have* to use Hibernate to use this functionality.

Comment: Also this is applicable only for JPQL queries and not for native queries