# JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA in my project.

I came to a query in which I need to make join operation on five tables. So I created a native query which returns five fields.

Now I want to convert the result object to java POJO class which contains the same five Strings.

Is there any way in JPA to directly cast that result to POJO object list ??

I came to the following solution ..

```
@NamedNativeQueries({  
    @NamedNativeQuery(  
        name = "nativeSQL",  
        query = "SELECT * FROM Actors",  
        resultClass = db.Actor.class),  
    @NamedNativeQuery(  
        name = "nativeSQL2",  
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Actors",  
        resultClass = XXXXX) // <--------------- problem  
})
```

Now here in resultClass, do we need to provide a class which is actual JPA entity ?
OR
We can convert it to any JAVA POJO class which contains the same column names ?

Comment: Check this answer. It has complete answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945

Comment: he's using jpa, not spring

Answer (score 120, accepted):

JPA provides an [`SqlResultSetMapping`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) that allows you to map whatever returns from your native query into an Entity <del>or a custom class</del>.

**EDIT** JPA 1.0 does not allow mapping to non-entity classes. Only in JPA 2.1 a [ConstructorResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) has been added to map return values a java class.

Also, for OP's problem with getting count it should be enough to define a result set mapping with a single [`ColumnResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ColumnResult.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here we are mapping our result with the entity with tha java entity class with "@EntityResult" and "@FieldResult" annotations. Thats fine. But here i need more clarity. Is is required that the class which we are mapping with the result must be a JPA entity class ? OR  can we use a simple POJO class which is not an entity buy which have all the required variable as the columns in  the result set.

Comment: @GunjanShah: best way to know is to give it a try :) also, an entity is just the same pojo, just with some annotations. as long as you're not trying to persist it, it will stay a pojo.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error that the class was not a known Entity. I ended up using this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024533/how-to-map-join-query-to-non-entity-class-in-jpa?rq=1 instead of trying to use a native query.

Comment: I think @SqlResultSetMapping only works mapping to entities not just to POJOs.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: that's right for jpa 1.0. in jpa 2.1 they've added `ConstructorResult` as one of parameters to `SqlResultSetMapping` that allows to use a pojo with all fields set in constructor. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I see another bitter truth: 
           ConstructorResult can map to a POJO .. 
           BUT ConstructorResult itself has to be in the Entity class

so Entity you can't avoid...and hence the bigger hard fact:

you need some result with don't care to primary-key - still you have to have @Id in Entity ...ridiculous right ?

Comment: Spring JPA 2.1 ,a very clear example in : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21

Answer (score 265):

I have found a couple of solutions to this.

**Using Mapped Entities (JPA 2.0)**

Using JPA 2.0 it is not possible to map a native query to a POJO, it can only be done with an entity.

For instance:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name,age FROM jedi_table", Jedi.class);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Jedi> items = (List<Jedi>) query.getResultList();
```

But in this case, `Jedi`, must be a mapped entity class.

An alternative to avoid the unchecked warning here, would be to use a named native query. So if we declare the native query in an entity

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
 name="jedisQry", 
 query = "SELECT name,age FROM jedis_table", 
 resultClass = Jedi.class)
```

Then, we can simply do:

```
TypedQuery<Jedi> query = em.createNamedQuery("jedisQry", Jedi.class);
List<Jedi> items = query.getResultList();
```

This is safer, but we are still restricted to use a mapped entity.

**Manual Mapping**

A solution I experimented a bit (before the arrival of JPA 2.1) was doing mapping against a POJO constructor using a bit of reflection.

```
public static <T> T map(Class<T> type, Object[] tuple){
   List<Class<?>> tupleTypes = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Object field : tuple){
      tupleTypes.add(field.getClass());
   }
   try {
      Constructor<T> ctor = type.getConstructor(tupleTypes.toArray(new Class<?>[tuple.length]));
      return ctor.newInstance(tuple);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

This method basically takes a tuple array (as returned by native queries) and maps it against a provided POJO class by looking for a constructor that has the same number of fields and of the same type.

Then we can use convenient methods like:

```
public static <T> List<T> map(Class<T> type, List<Object[]> records){
   List<T> result = new LinkedList<>();
   for(Object[] record : records){
      result.add(map(type, record));
   }
   return result;
}

public static <T> List<T> getResultList(Query query, Class<T> type){
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Object[]> records = query.getResultList();
  return map(type, records);
}
```

And we can simply use this technique as follows:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name,age FROM jedis_table");
List<Jedi> jedis = getResultList(query, Jedi.class);
```

**JPA 2.1 with @SqlResultSetMapping**

With the arrival of JPA 2.1, we can use the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation to solve the problem.

We need to declare a result set mapping somewhere in a entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="JediResult", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Jedi.class, 
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name="name"), @ColumnResult(name="age")})
})
```

And then we simply do:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name,age FROM jedis_table", "JediResult");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Jedi> samples = query.getResultList();
```

Of course, in this case `Jedi` needs not to be an mapped entity. It can be a regular POJO.

**Using XML Mapping**

I am one of those that find adding all these `@SqlResultSetMapping` pretty invasive in my entities, and I particularly dislike the definition of named queries within entities, so alternatively I do all this in the `META-INF/orm.xml` file:

```
<named-native-query name="GetAllJedi" result-set-mapping="JediMapping">
    <query>SELECT name,age FROM jedi_table</query>
</named-native-query>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="JediMapping">
        <constructor-result target-class="org.answer.model.Jedi">
            <column name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <column name="age" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        </constructor-result>
    </sql-result-set-mapping>
```

And those are all the solutions I know. The last two are the ideal way if we can use JPA 2.1.

Comment: Sidenote: I just used the JPA 2.0 approach with JPA2.1 dependency, and it failed. So probably this is not downwards compatible...

Comment: How can we map resultset for @Query annotaion?

Comment: what do you mean by "somewhere in a entity" ? My Pojo is not a JPA Entity can't I declare the @SqlResultSetMapping in my POJO? I'm interested in the JPA 2.1 solutions. Please be a bit more precise.

Comment: @Alboz The `@SqlResultSetMapping` must be placed in an entity because that's what JPA is going to read the metadata from. You cannot expect JPA to inspect your POJOs. The entity in which you place the mapping is irrelevant, perhaps the one that is more related to your POJO results. Alternatively the mapping could be expressed in XML to avoid the coupling with a totally unrelated entity.

Comment: Is it possible for the constructorresult to use a class that has a nested class?

Comment: If using JPA 2.1 with `@SqlResultSetMapping` it may be worth noting that the `Jedi` class will require an all-arg constructor and  the `@ColumnResult` annotation may need the `type` attribute added to conversions which might not be implicit (I needed to add  `type = ZonedDateTime.class` for some columns).

Comment: I want to add, that ResultSetMapping does not work with Long instead of a POJO. Might have to do with Glenn's comment about the constructor requirement.

Comment: I am getting always an "No query defined for that name". I just copied your example. I am jusing JPA 2.0. Have you any clue?

Comment: Something quick to add to this answer is that if you are using Spring to wire the EntityManager you can tell it to read the ORM XML file. 

    <bean id="myEntityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="model"/>
        <property name="mappingResources" value="META-INF/orm.xml" />
        ...
    </bean>

Comment: I dont like this solution because you need to add @SqlResultSetMapping to and entity that may have no relation to the pojo.

Comment: @fjkjava If you had read the entire answer, you would have noticed that the last section addresses precisely that issue.

Comment: I saw that but i dont like that in xml also, no xml configs in my application, why can't they let us use that as a part of StoredProcedureQuery or @Repository

Comment: @fjkjava do not understand. Native query and stored procedure query are two things, right?

Comment: Can you give an example of how would be the constructor of the Jedi class?.

Comment: Could you answer the following question. Suppose we have two tables (A and B) and make `SELECT B.X, B.Y FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ...`. Will JPA provider convert the results of such query to B entities?

Comment: What chances of automated mapping do I have, when I need to query a SQL view (that does not have any Entity) and want to map a few columns to a projection-like DTO? I could not get working using SqlResultSetMapping. Only way I could get data into my object so far is by using native query and mapping results manually

Comment: Thanks for a great solution, I like the one with XML mapping mainly for the reason of not having the query and the mapper scattered over several places. Anyway, I would wish a more elegant solution from the JPA authors as all the solutions are kind of workaround.

Comment: Man, thank you soo much for a solution with XML mapping. For some reason, my IntelliJ IDEA doesn't autocomplete exactly this solution, so I dig half of the internet (incl. docs) to find this answer :)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, with JPA 2.1 it's easy. You have very useful Annotations. They simplify your life.

First declare your native query, then your result set mapping (which defines the mapping of the data returned by the database to your POJOs). Write your POJO class to refer to (not included here for brevity). Last but not least: create a method in a DAO (for example) to call the query. This worked for me in a dropwizard (1.0.0) app.

First declare a native query in an entity class (@Entity):

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery (
name = "domain.io.MyClass.myQuery",
query = "Select a.colA, a.colB from Table a",
resultSetMapping = "mappinMyNativeQuery")   // must be the same name as in the SqlResultSetMapping declaration
```

Underneath you can add the resultset mapping declaration:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
name = "mapppinNativeQuery",  // same as resultSetMapping above in NativeQuery
   classes = {
      @ConstructorResult( 
          targetClass = domain.io.MyMapping.class,
          columns = {
               @ColumnResult( name = "colA", type = Long.class),  
               @ColumnResult( name = "colB", type = String.class)
          }
      )
   } 
)
```

Later in a DAO you can refer to the query as

```
public List<domain.io.MyMapping> findAll() {
        return (namedQuery("domain.io.MyClass.myQuery").list());
    }
```

That's it.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think you have missed a parenthesis after the first @ColumnResult annotation.

Comment: There are mistakes in the code, but easy to correct.
For example: "resulSetMapping =" should be "resultSetMapping ="

Comment: I see another bitter truth: 
       NamedNativeQuery  & SqlResultSetMapping has to be
        in a @Entity class

Answer (score 12):

If you use `Spring-jpa`, this is a supplement to the answers and this question. Please correct this if any flaws. I have mainly used three methods to achieve "mapping result `Object[]` to a pojo" based on what practical need I meet:

1. JPA built in method is enough.
2. JPA built in method is not enough, but a customized `sql` with its `Entity` are enough.
3. The former 2 failed, and I have to use a `nativeQuery`.
   Here are the examples.
   The pojo expected:

   ```
   public class Antistealingdto {

       private String secretKey;

       private Integer successRate;

       // GETTERs AND SETTERs

       public Antistealingdto(String secretKey, Integer successRate) {
           this.secretKey = secretKey;
           this.successRate = successRate;
       }
   }
   ```

**Method 1**: Change the pojo into an interface:

```
public interface Antistealingdto {
    String getSecretKey();
    Integer getSuccessRate();
}
```

And repository:

```
interface AntiStealingRepository extends CrudRepository<Antistealing, Long> {
    Antistealingdto findById(Long id);
}
```

**Method 2**: 
Repository:

```
@Query("select new AntistealingDTO(secretKey, successRate) from Antistealing where ....")
Antistealing whatevernamehere(conditions);
```

Note: parameter sequence of POJO constructor must be identical in both POJO definition and sql.

**Method 3**:
Use `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@NamedNativeQuery` in `Entity` as the example in Edwin Dalorzo's answer.

The first two methods would call many in-the-middle handlers, like customized converters. For example, `AntiStealing` defines a `secretKey`, before it is persisted, a converter is inserted to encrypt it. This would result in the first 2 methods returning a converted back `secretKey` which is not what I want. While the method 3 would overcome the converter, and returned `secretKey` would be the same as it is stored (an encrypted one).

Comment: The Method 1 doesn't actually require Spring and works with pure Hibernate.

Comment: @MartinVysny yes, M1 is JPQL. any projects implements JPQL should support it. In this way, maybe M2 is also widely supported?

Comment: IMO Method 2 is simple to implement and maintain, and is MUCH simpler than other over-complex methods for mapping query results to POJO (Most of them don't work for me).
Note that when invoking the ctor, the class name should be fully qualified.

Answer (score 12):

Unwrap procedure can be performed to assign results to non-entity(which is Beans/POJO). The procedure is as following.

```
List<JobDTO> dtoList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql)
        .setParameter("userId", userId)
        .unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(JobDTO.class)).list();
```

The usage is for JPA-Hibernate implementation.

Comment: note that `JobDTO` should have default constructor. Or you might implement your own transformer based on `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` implementation.

Comment: Why setParameter ?

Comment: org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer is showing the deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to use so **projections**. It can map query results directly to interfaces and is easier to implement than using SqlResultSetMapping.

An example is shown below:

```
@Repository
public interface PeopleRepository extends JpaRepository<People, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.name AS name, COUNT(dp.people_id) AS count " +
        "FROM people p INNER JOIN dream_people dp " +
        "ON p.id = dp.people_id " +
        "WHERE p.user_id = :userId " +
        "GROUP BY dp.people_id " +
        "ORDER BY p.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PeopleDTO> findByPeopleAndCountByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.name AS name, COUNT(dp.people_id) AS count " +
        "FROM people p INNER JOIN dream_people dp " +
        "ON p.id = dp.people_id " +
        "WHERE p.user_id = :userId " +
        "GROUP BY dp.people_id " +
        "ORDER BY p.name", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<PeopleDTO> findByPeopleAndCountByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);

}



// Interface to which result is projected
public interface PeopleDTO {

    String getName();

    Long getCount();

}
```

The fields from projected interface must match fields in this entity. Otherwise field mapping might break.

Also if you use `SELECT table.column` notation always define aliases matching names from entity as shown in example.

Comment: native query and projections don't go well together.

Comment: I couldn't get the field mapping to work quite right - most values kept coming back as null

Answer (score 8):

In hibernate you  can use this code to easily map your native query.

```
private List < Map < String, Object >> getNativeQueryResultInMap() {
String mapQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM AB_SERVICE three ";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(mapQueryStr);
NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;
nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List < Map < String, Object >> result = query.getResultList();
for (Map map: result) {
    System.out.println("after request  ::: " + map);
}
return result;}
```

Comment: This is a very nice and useful solution. It works for me. Using this List < Map < String, Object >> result I can do anything. I can set value in POJO or do convert in JSON or anything.

Answer (score 4):

First declare following annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NativeQueryResultEntity {
}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NativeQueryResultColumn {
    int index();
}
```

Then annotate your POJO as follows:

```
@NativeQueryResultEntity
public class ClassX {
    @NativeQueryResultColumn(index=0)
    private String a;

    @NativeQueryResultColumn(index=1)
    private String b;
}
```

Then write annotation processor:

```
public class NativeQueryResultsMapper {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NativeQueryResultsMapper.class);

    public static <T> List<T> map(List<Object[]> objectArrayList, Class<T> genericType) {
        List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>();
        List<Field> mappingFields = getNativeQueryResultColumnAnnotatedFields(genericType);
        try {
            for (Object[] objectArr : objectArrayList) {
                T t = genericType.newInstance();
                for (int i = 0; i < objectArr.length; i++) {
                    BeanUtils.setProperty(t, mappingFields.get(i).getName(), objectArr[i]);
                }
                ret.add(t);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException ie) {
            log.debug("Cannot instantiate: ", ie);
            ret.clear();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            log.debug("Illegal access: ", iae);
            ret.clear();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
            log.debug("Cannot invoke method: ", ite);
            ret.clear();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get ordered list of fields
    private static <T> List<Field> getNativeQueryResultColumnAnnotatedFields(Class<T> genericType) {
        Field[] fields = genericType.getDeclaredFields();
        List<Field> orderedFields = Arrays.asList(new Field[fields.length]);
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].isAnnotationPresent(NativeQueryResultColumn.class)) {
                NativeQueryResultColumn nqrc = fields[i].getAnnotation(NativeQueryResultColumn.class);
                orderedFields.set(nqrc.index(), fields[i]);
            }
        }
        return orderedFields;
    }
}
```

Use above framework as follows:

```
String sql = "select a,b from x order by a";
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);

List<ClassX> results = NativeQueryResultsMapper.map(q.getResultList(), ClassX.class);
```

Comment: Which package is `BeanUtils` in?

Answer (score 4):

Using Hibernate :

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void accessUser() {
EntityManager em = repo.getEntityManager();
    org.hibernate.Session session = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
    org.hibernate.SQLQuery q = (org.hibernate.SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT u.username, u.name, u.email, 'blabla' as passe, login_type as loginType FROM users u").addScalar("username", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("name", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("email", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("passe", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("loginType", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User2DTO.class));

    List<User2DTO> userList = q.list();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We have resolved the issue using following way :

```
   //Add actual table name here in Query
    final String sqlQuery = "Select a.* from ACTORS a"
    // add your entity manager here 
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery,Actors.class);
    //List contains the mapped entity data.
    List<Actors> list = (List<Actors>) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since others have already mentioned all the possible solutions, I am sharing my workaround solution.

In my situation with `Postgres 9.4`, while working with `Jackson`,

```
//Convert it to named native query.
List<String> list = em.createNativeQuery("select cast(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(a))) as text) from myschema.actors a")
                   .getResultList();

List<ActorProxy> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(list.get(0), new TypeReference<List<ActorProxy>>() {});
```

I am sure you can find same for other databases.

Also FYI, [JPA 2.0 native query results as map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595328/jpa-2-0-native-query-results-as-map/46190527#46190527)

Answer (score 2):

Old style using ResultSet

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void accessUser() {
    EntityManager em = this.getEntityManager();
    org.hibernate.Session session = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
    session.doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT u.username, u.name, u.email, 'blabla' as passe, login_type as loginType FROM users u")) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " (" + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) + ") / ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Found username " + rs.getString("USERNAME") + " name " + rs.getString("NAME") + " email " + rs.getString("EMAIL") + " passe " + rs.getString("PASSE") + " email " + rs.getInt("LOGIN_TYPE"));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map the custom query result directly to an entity without writing any code to map, try this way. In my experience, it is the most convenient way to do, but the downside is to lose the benefit of hibernate ddl-auto:

1. Disable hibernate validation by removing the `hibernate.ddl-auto`. If not doing this, hibernate can complain about missing table in database.
2. Create a pojo with `@Entity` for the custom result set without table mapping, something like:

   ```
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @Entity
   public class MyCustomeResult implements Serializable {
       @Id
       private Long id;

       @Column(name = "name")
       private String name;
   }
   ```
3. In repository, use the entity to map directly from `query.getResultList()`

   ```
   public List<MyCustomeResult> findByExampleCustomQuery(Long test) {
        String sql = "select id, name from examples where id =:test";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, MyCustomeResult.class);
        return query.setParameter("test", test).getResultList();
    }
   ```

Comment: This is what I needed. This selects and populates fields for nested entities however so need to be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits here, but I had similar question and found following simple solution/example for me:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
...
    final String sql = " SELECT * FROM STORE "; // select from the table STORE
    final Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Store.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Store> results = (List<Store>) sqlQuery.getResultList();
```

In my case I had to use SQL parts defined in Strings somewhere else, so I could not just use NamedNativeQuery.

Comment: as soon as we returning entity. nothing fancy. problem is when you try to map the result to an unmanaged POJO.

Answer (score 0):

See example below for using a POJO as pseudo entity to retrieve result from native query without using complex SqlResultSetMapping. Just need two annotations, a bare @Enity and a dummy @Id in your POJO. @Id can be used on any field of your choice, an @Id field can have duplicate keys but not null values.

Since @Enity does not map to any physical table, so this POJO is called a pseudo entity.

Environment: eclipselink 2.5.0-RC1, jpa-2.1.0, mysql-connector-java-5.1.14

You can download complete maven project [here](https://github.com/jonathanluo/jpa)

Native query is based on mysql sample employees db
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jpa-mysql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.moonwave.jpa.model.pojo.Employee</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Employee.java

```
package org.moonwave.jpa.model.pojo;

@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
protected Long empNo;

protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String title;

public Long getEmpNo() {
    return empNo;
}
public void setEmpNo(Long empNo) {
    this.empNo = empNo;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}   
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("empNo: ").append(empNo);
    sb.append(", firstName: ").append(firstName);
    sb.append(", lastName: ").append(lastName);
    sb.append(", title: ").append(title);
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

EmployeeNativeQuery.java

```
public class EmployeeNativeQuery {
private EntityManager em;
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-mysql");
    em=emf.createEntityManager();
}
public void tearDown()throws Exception {
    em.close();
    emf.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void query() {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select e.emp_no as empNo, e.first_name as firstName, e.last_name as lastName," + 
            "t.title from employees e join titles t on e.emp_no = t.emp_no", Employee.class);
    query.setMaxResults(30);
    List<Employee> list = (List<Employee>) query.getResultList();
    int i = 0;
    for (Object emp : list) {
        System.out.println(++i + ": " + emp.toString());
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EmployeeNativeQuery test = new EmployeeNativeQuery();
    try {
        test.setUp();
        test.query();
        test.tearDown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since your `list` is, allegedly, a list of `Employee`, why is your for-each loop iterating over a type `Object`? If you write your for-each loop as `for(Employee emp : list)` then you'd discover that your answer is wrong and the contents of your list are not employees and that that warning you suppressed had the purpose to alert you about this potential mistake.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is used to suppress warning for     `List<Employee> list = (List<Employee>) query.getResultList();` Change `for (Object emp : list)` to `for (Employee emp : list)` is better, but no errors if kept as `Object emp` since list is an instance of `List<Employee>`. I changed the code in git project but not here to keep your comment relevant to original post

Comment: the problem is that your query does not return an list of employes, but a an array of objects. Your suppressed warning is hiding that. In the momento that you try to convert any of those to an employee, you will get an error, a cast exception.

Comment: Look at `Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * ...", Employee.class);` and persistence.xml, the native query does return a list of  Employee. I just checked out and run the project w/o issue. If you setup mysql sample employees db locally, you should be able to run the project as well

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. But in that case your answer does not satisfy the question, because this was about using a regular POJO as the target object, and your answer is using `Employee` which I assume is an entity. Isn't it?

Comment: Look at my comment in Employee.java, `A POJO used as pseudo entity to retrieve result from native query. This entity does not map to any physical table. Minimum annotations are @Enity and @Id ...
`
this relieves user from writing `SqlResultSetMapping` stuff. It is a `pseudo entity` which asks JPA to load this class, no table mapping is needed, all needed is the fields

Comment: This does not answer the question as JPA entity is still required.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Spring, you can use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper`

Here is an example:

```
public List query(String objectType, String namedQuery)
{
  String rowMapper = objectType + "RowMapper";
  // then by reflection you can instantiate and use. The RowMapper classes need to follow the naming specific convention to follow such implementation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate :

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void accessUser() {
    EntityManager em = repo.getEntityManager();
    org.hibernate.Session session = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
    org.hibernate.SQLQuery q = (org.hibernate.SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT u.username, u.name, u.email, 'blabla' as passe, login_type as loginType FROM users u")
        .addScalar("username", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("name", StringType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("email", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("passe", StringType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("loginType", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User2DTO.class));

    List<User2DTO> userList = q.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things as mentioned in the above answers. The SQLmapper was very confusing as to where to put it. Non managed POJOs only were a problem. I was trying various ways and one easy way I got it worked was as usual. I am using hibernate-jpa-2.1.

```
List<TestInfo> testInfoList = factory.createNativeQuery(QueryConstants.RUNNING_TEST_INFO_QUERY)
                    .getResultList();
```

The only thing to take care was that POJO has same member variable names as that of the query ( all in lowercase). And apparently I didn't even need to tell the target class along with query as we do with TypedQueries in JPQL.

**TestInfo.class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TestInfo {

    private String emailid;
    private Long testcount;

    public TestInfo(String emailId, Long testCount) {
        super();
        this.emailid = emailId;
        this.testcount = testCount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "Database View" like entity a.k.a immutable entity is super easy for this case.

#### Normal entity

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
data class Person(
  @Id
  val id: Long = -1,
  val firstName: String = "",
  val lastName: String? = null
)
```

#### View like entity

```kotlin
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("""
select
    p.id,
    concat(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) as full_name
from people p
""")
data class PersonMin(
  @Id
  val id: Long,
  val fullName: String,
)
```

In any repository we can create query function/method just like:

```kotlin
@Query(value = "select p from PersonMin p")
fun findPeopleMinimum(pageable: Pageable): Page<PersonMin>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//PackageCustomerResponse Class

/**
 * @author : azad
 * @mailto : azadsmc@gmail.com
 * @created : 10/17/2023, Tuesday
 **/
public interface PackageCustomerResponse {

    Long getCustomerId();

    String getCustomerName();

    Long getPackageId();

    String getPackageName();

    LocalDate getStartDate();

}


//Repository

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

@Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value="SELECT c.customer_id as customerId, c.customer_name as 
  customerName, pa.package_id as packageId, " +
                    "pa.package_name as packageName, pa.start_date as startDate 
  FROM customers c "+
                    "INNER JOIN customer_packages p ON p.customer_id = 
  c.customer_id "+
                    "INNER JOIN packages pa ON pa.package_id = p.package_id")

  List<PackageCustomerResponse> findPackageCustomer();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to converting SQL query to POJO class collection ,

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).addEntity(Actors.class);
List<Actors> list = (List<Actors>) query.list();
return list;
```

Answer (score -1):

If the query is not too complicated you can do something like this. In my case i needed to use a H2 FT_Search result query to make another query.

```
var ftSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH(\'something\', 0, 0)";
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] result : results) {
    var newQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + (String) result[0];
    models.addAll(entityManager.createNativeQuery(newQuery, Model.class).getResultList());
  }
```

There are probably cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Use `DTO Design Pattern`. It was used in `EJB 2.0`. Entity was container managed. `DTO Design Pattern` is used to solve this problem.
But, it might be use now, when the application is developed `Server Side` and `Client Side` separately.`DTO` is used when `Server side` doesn't want to pass/return `Entity` with annotation to `Client Side`.

DTO Example :

PersonEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String address;

    public PersonEntity(){

    }
    public PersonEntity(String id, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }
    //getter and setter

}
```

PersonDTO.java

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String id;
    private String address;

    public PersonDTO() {
    }
    public PersonDTO(String id, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }

    //getter and setter 
}
```

DTOBuilder.java

```
public class DTOBuilder() {
    public static PersonDTO buildPersonDTO(PersonEntity person) {
        return new PersonDTO(person.getId(). person.getAddress());
    }
}
```

EntityBuilder.java <-- it mide be need

```
public class EntityBuilder() {
    public static PersonEntity buildPersonEntity(PersonDTO person) {
        return new PersonEntity(person.getId(). person.getAddress());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Here I dont need DTO pattern. My requirement is not to hide the annotation details from the client. So I dont need to create one more POJO in my app. My requirement is to cast the result set to qa pojo that is not an JAVA entity but simple POJO class that have same fields as result set columns.