# JPA Native Query select and cast object

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have got an Object `Admin` which extends `User`. By default both Objects are in the table `User_` of my Derby Database (included fields from `Admin`). Normally I'd select an `User` like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root user= query.from(User.class);
Predicate predicateId = cb.equal(category.get("id"), id);
query.select(user).where(predicateId);
return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

However due to the complexity of my query I'm using a native query like this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT USER.* FROM USER_ AS USER WHERE ID = ?");
query.setParameter(1, id);
return (User) query.getSingleResult();
```

Though this throws a cast exception. I figure this is due to any fields from `Admin`.

My question is, how can I select a `User` using a native query with an equal result as the first example (including the same values for `@LOB` and `@ManyToOne` (et cetera) as the JPQL query would return)?

Comment: what makes the query too complex for JPQL?

Comment: @damo This is a shortend example, the real query contains a number of subqueries, `SUM`, `COALESCENSE`, `CASE` et cetera.

Comment: Check this answer. It has complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You might want to try one of the following ways:

- #### *Using* the method `createNativeQuery(sqlString, resultClass)`

  Native queries can also be defined dynamically using the `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()` API.

  ```
  String sql = "SELECT USER.* FROM USER_ AS USER WHERE ID = ?";

  Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, User.class);
  query.setParameter(1, id);
  User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
  ```
- #### *Using* the annotation `@NamedNativeQuery`

  Native queries are defined through the `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@NamedNativeQueries`
  annotations, or `<named-native-query>` XML element.

  ```
  @NamedNativeQuery(
      name="complexQuery",
      query="SELECT USER.* FROM USER_ AS USER WHERE ID = ?",
      resultClass=User.class
  )
  public class User { ... }

  Query query = em.createNamedQuery("complexQuery", User.class);
  query.setParameter(1, id);
  User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
  ```

You can read more in the excellent open book [***Java Persistence***](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) (available in [**PDF**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Java_Persistence.pdf)).

<sup>───────

**NOTE**: With regard to use of **`getSingleResult()`**, see [Why you should never use `getSingleResult()` in JPA](http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/).</sup>

Comment: @PaulVargas What if the result is an Integer and not an entity

Comment: @PaulVargas, I would recommend doing something like this:

Integer val = (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
However, I usually recommend against query.getSingleResult() as it throws to many checked exceptions. If you get your results as a list, you can then handle no results and more than one accordingly.

Comment: Hey, @Joe. Thanks! -- I continued with `query.getSingleResult()` because the *OP*. :)

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

`createNativeQuery` will always return a `Query`:

```
public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass);
```

Calling `getResultList` on a `Query` returns `List`:

```
List getResultList()
```

When assigning (or casting) to `List<MyEntity>`, an unchecked assignment warning is produced.

Whereas, `createQuery` will return a `TypedQuery`:

```
public <T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass);
```

Calling `getResultList` on a `TypedQuery` returns `List<X>`.

```
List<X> getResultList();
```

This is properly typed and will not give a warning.

With `createNativeQuery`, using `ObjectMapper` seems to be the only way to get rid of the warning. Personally, I choose to suppress the warning, as I see this as a deficiency in the library and not something I should have to worry about.

Answer (score 8):

When your native query is based on joins, in that case you can get the result as list of objects and process it.

one simple example.

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

    String nativeQuery = "select name,age from users where id=?";   
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery);
    query.setParameter(1,id);

    List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();

    for(Object[] q1 : list){

        String name = q1[0].toString();
        //..
        //do something more on 
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection/47234623#47234623)

For `Postgres 9.4`,

```
List<String> list = em.createNativeQuery("select cast(row_to_json(u) as text) from myschema.USER_ u WHERE ID = ?")
                   .setParameter(1, id).getResultList();

User map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(list.get(0), User.class);
```

Comment: which way is good for pass native query?
1) Using EntityManager 
2) Using JpaRepository Interface

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is using [Interface projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) .

At the beginning, I created a DTO class but it just didn't work, replacing the class with an interface like this works great:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT vat as vatRate, SUM(...) as amount from ...", nativeQuery = true)
List<VatReportLine> getSalesVats();


public interface VatReportLine {

    double getVatRate();

    long getAmount();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> First of all create a model POJO

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_std_user")
public class StdUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "class_id")
    public int classId;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    public String userName;
    //getter,setter
}
```

> Controller

```
import com.example.demo.models.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<StdUser> actionIndex() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); // Without parameter
        List<StdUser> arr_cust = (List<StdUser>)em
                .createQuery("SELECT c FROM StdUser c")
                .getResultList();
        return arr_cust;
    }

    @GetMapping("/paramter")
    public List actionJoin() {
        int id = 3;
        String userName = "Suresh Shrestha";
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); // With parameter
        List arr_cust = em
                .createQuery("SELECT c FROM StdUser c WHERE c.classId = :Id ANd c.userName = :UserName")
                .setParameter("Id",id)
                .setParameter("UserName",userName)
                .getResultList();
        return arr_cust;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to write your data access code inside the rest controller. Store your data access code in @ Repository classes. Call your repositories from @ Service classes. Access the @ Service classes from the @ RestController.