# playframework selecting from h2 database

Tags: jpa, h2, playframework-2.2

I am trying downloading all records from table in h2 buildin database in playframework.
I am facing an error:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM TABLE]]
```

Method CODE i class Table:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public static Result view() {
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
    List<Table> downloaded_from_db = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println(downloaded_from_db.getClass());

    return ok(view.render("none"));
}
```

Please help me. I would like to see downloaded records in console in simple view.
Please give me some tips or good tutorial.

After changing my class loooks like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public static Result view() {
    List<MedicalIncidents> data = JPA.em()
           .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MedicalIncident")
           //.createQuery("Select m from MedicalIncident m")
           .getResultList();
    System.out.println(data);
```

AND I think it works, cause I have 2 entries in that table in database:

But System.out.println(data) return in  plaay console:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@70a0c9be, [Ljava.lang.Object;@4c1d12b6]
```

But it should return this object by model name like in example: computer-database-jpa:

```
[models.Computer@214c6fde, models.Computer@63728eb3, models.Computer@75f6bcc6, models.Computer@19e3a7ab, models.Computer@3114d8d4, models.Computer@4fa75f78, models.Computer@756ce822, models.Computer@40fc4c68, models.Computer@73fc612c, models.Computer@3e4fcb31]
```

So I think that there is something wrong with it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mxied SQL queries with JPQL query. The method you used `createQuery` needs an JPQL query:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e
```

Also please note in JPQL there is no `SELECT *`. If you want to write a SQL query, use the method `em.createNtiveQuery()`.

Comment: It help me thanks. Now I am having another issue. I've edited my post. Look above

Comment: Please mark this question as solved and post another question.

Comment: @masterdany88 Before asking your new question, see this question/answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708946/jpa-native-query-select-and-cast-object