# How to write custom between spring data JPA query?

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an 
**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class PromoAmtRange implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "low")
private Integer low;

@Column(name = "high")
private Integer high;

@Column(name = "threshold")
private Integer threshold;

//
constructor & getters setters
}
```

and its 
**Repository**

```
public interface PromoAmtRangeRepository extends JpaRepository<PromoAmtRange,Long> {

@Query("SELECT pa FROM PromoAmtRange pa WHERE :intValue BETWEEN pa.low AND pa.high")
PromoAmtRange findByThreshold(@Param("intValue") Integer intValue);
}
```

**Note :** as you can see intValue is not a member variable of entity class.

I want to get data when intValue fall **BETWEEN** low and high?

for example I have database entry as shown in picture:

[image]

if my intValue is **50** I should get first row i.e.

```
1 | 0 | 100 | 30
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: did you try executing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or top, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be returned.

Try:

```
public interface PromoAmtRangeRepository extends JpaRepository<PromoAmtRange,Long> {

@Query("SELECT pa FROM PromoAmtRange pa WHERE :intValue BETWEEN pa.low AND pa.high")
   List<PromoAmtRange> findByThreshold(@Param("intValue") Integer intValue,Pageable pageable);
}
```

Implementation class:

```
List<PromoAmtRange> result = jpaRepository.findByThreshold(intValue, new PageRequest(0,10));
```

Comment: it works .. I used List<PromoAmtRange> instead of  Page<PromoAmtRange> without these two i was getting follwing  exception; org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Answer (score 0):

You can user JPA Native query. (there is usable answers [about native query and maping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709311/1075369))

you can use native query [like this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/06/09/jpa-native-select-sql-query-example/)