# Spring data. get custom values select(not entity)

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-repositories, hibernate-native-query

I have this query

```
String  query = "select ig.p1,
       ig.p2,
       ig.p3, 
       tg.p4
  from mytable ig, mytable2 tg
 where ..... and ....";
```

And I have DTO

```
public class MyDto{
//constructor
private String p1;
private String p2;
private String p3;
private String p4;
...
//getters/setters
}
```

I need get this select and mapping to DTO.

I create this in my DTO

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="findReport",
        classes={
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass=MyDto.class,
                        columns={
                                @ColumnResult(name="p1",type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="p2", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="p3", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name="p4", type = String.class),
                        }
                )
        }
)
```

And create DAO/Repository

```
@Component
public class ReportRepositoryImpl implements ReportRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Report findReportSelect() {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                "query","findReport");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Collection<MyDto> dto = query.getResultList();

        Iterable<MyDto> itr = dto;
        return (MyDto)itr;
    }
}
```

But I have error `unchecked`

My quations
1. How can I fix this error and what this error means?
2. Is there more easy way get this result?

Answer (score 0):

The unchecked warning is because `query.getResultList()` returns an untyped `Collection` instead of `Collection<MyDto>`. If you call one of the `EntityManager` methods that returns a `TypedQuery<T>` instead of `Query` it will clear that warning. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709311/125344) has some good guidance for using `@NamedNativeQuery` with `EntityManager.createNamedQuery(name, class)` to accomplish that.