# sql convert to hql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT s_store_name ,
   sum(ss_net_profit)
FROM store_sales ,
     date_dim ,
     store,
  (SELECT ca_zip
   FROM
 ( SELECT substr(ca_zip,1,5) ca_zip
  FROM customer_address
  WHERE substr(ca_zip,1,5) IN ( '27385',  '79307', '15492') INTERSECT
    SELECT ca_zip
    FROM
      (SELECT substr(ca_zip,1,5) ca_zip,
              count(*) cnt
       FROM customer_address,
            customer
       WHERE ca_address_sk = c_current_addr_sk
         AND c_preferred_cust_flag='Y'
       GROUP BY ca_zip
       HAVING count(*) > 10)A1)A2) V1
WHERE ss_store_sk = s_store_sk
  AND ss_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk
  AND d_qoy = 1
  AND d_year = 2002
  AND (substr(s_zip,1,2) = substr(V1.ca_zip,1,2))
GROUP BY s_store_name
ORDER BY s_store_name LIMIT 100;
```

now ,I want to convert it to hql,but hive don't support `INTERSECT`,what should I do? In addition hive seem to be dont't support `as` either.

Comment: Is executing this query as 'native query' an option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708946/jpa-native-query-select-and-cast-object

Comment: I save it as a file and `hive -f filename;`

Comment: You can rewrite this sql to make it hive compatible. For INTERSECT, you can use an INNER JOIN. Also you would need to use a GROUP BY or DISTINCT if you have don't have a pure one-to-one relationship.

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matrix42 What version HIVE are you using?  when you say 'as' are you reffering to an alias? select a.zip as ZIP,  ?  Aliasing works fine for me on Apache Hive, HIVE JDBC, Beeline (version 1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950)

Comment: @AM_Hawk It‘s my fault ,hive support `as`