# Spring Data: Order by nested property

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using `JpaRepository` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor` from Spring Data and i'm having a problem to sort the method `findAll(specification, pageable, sort)`

I want to sort the result of a specification by a nested property from the main repo class. This is my case:

the main class

```
class Foo {
    //other properties
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
    private Set<Bar> bars;
}
```

the ordering class

```
class Bar {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fooId")
    private Foo foo;

    //I WANT TO SORT BY THIS FIELD
    @Column
    private Date date;
}
```

and this is my repo

```
interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<Foo , Long>, 
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo>{
    //just jparepo methods
}
```

this is how i'm trying order this result

```
void anymethod(){
    Sort sort = new Sort(Bar_.date.getName());
    PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(anyPage, anyMaxResultsNum, sort);
    repository.findAll(anySpecification, pr);

}
```

and when i run this i'm getting the "PropertyReferenceException: No property date found for type Foo!"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`@javax.persistence.OrderBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) annotation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
@OrderBy("date")
private Set<Bar> bars;
```

Comment: it's a good approach but i want to sorting by this field in just one time. If i use this i'm sorting by bars.date in all of repository.findAll calls

Comment: @pablobaldez Then you're right, this solution won't suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` field is defined on `Bar`, not `Foo`.  So define a `BarRepo` and call `findAll()` on the `BarRepo` using the date sort. Since you have a bi-directional association, you can get `Foo` from each `Bar` returned by `findAll()` and filter out any duplicate `Foo`.

**Or** you can try using `@Query` annotation on a `FooRepo` interface method to define [native sql to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948795/is-it-possible-to-use-raw-sql-within-a-spring-repository).

Comment: I have many specifications works to Foo, so the FooRepo is excencial.

Comment: i want to do some like this: "new Sort (Order("bars.date")) //this working as well" - 
but using metamodel classes. You know how can i navigate between metamodel properties?

Comment: If you want to sort a list of `Foo`, you need to pick one `Bar` for each `Foo` to sort by, right?

Comment: Yes. I had thought the join colunm resolve this for me, and the repo would do this automaticaly

Comment: There's no way for JPARepository to infer which `Bar` to pick from list to sort `Foo` by. What should JPARepository do if a `Foo` has empty `Bar` list?

Comment: I understand what you say and don't have many knowledge about jparepository, but with sql this will works

Comment: "select * from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.fooId order by bar.date" - this will works, right? How can i do this with criteria,jpa repo (for foo) and specifications (that returns predicates)