# Spring JPA Repository Custom Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This custom query works(this is just a basic query to illustrate the problem):

```
public interface BookQueryRepositoryExample extends Repository<Book, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from Book b where b.name=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Book> findByName(String name);
}
```

but I need another custom query where the `where` clause will be constructed dynamically before calling the method.

```
public interface BookQueryRepositoryExample extends Repository<Book, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from Book b where ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Book> findByWhatever(String qry);
}
```

But I am not able to make it work. Is there any workaround?

Updated: 6/16/2017

Just want to mention this that the field I am searching is 'denormalized' form. The values can look like these(below). So my query has a series of like statements

Sample 1:

```
name:John Smith;address1:123 Xyz St;city:New York;zip:12345;country:USA;id:ABC1234;email:js@abc.com;
```

Sample 2:Rearranged

```
address1:123 Xyz St;zip:12345;email:js@abc.com;name:John Smith;country:USA;id:ABC1234;city:New York;
```

Sample 3:Missing strings/text

```
zip:12345;email:js@abc.com;name:John Smith;id:ABC1234;city:New York;
```

Comment: No, as that is not how parameter substitution works. Why not use JPQL or Criteria queries to do dynamic queries. (Your first custom query you don't even need only the method `findByName` is already enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok. Will look into that Criteria  queries. Thanks. I did not really use that findByName method. I kinda just put it out there for emphasis.

Comment: You can visit this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945

Answer (score 2):

This won't work, at least not with this approach.

The placeholders in a query don't just get replaced with some arbitrary `String`, but are variables, that can only stand in for something you would provide as a literal otherwise.

But as @M. Deinum pointed out there are alternatives: You can [write a custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and use

- JPA Criteria API
- JPQL
- Specifications
- QueryDSL

See this article for some examples: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 2):

Work around for this would be like, you can have a class to execute dynamic queries by injecting the `EntityManager` as shown below:

```
//Pseudo code
@Repository
public class SomeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public List<Book> findByWhatever(String qry){
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qry);
        List<Object[]> books = q.getResultList();

        // Your logic goes here

        // return something
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to implement it using the springframework Repository or JpaRepository. Any thoughts?

Comment: JPARepository, I had tried long ago but hard luck. Later implemented the same as shown above. As `Spring-Boot` can inject the `EnityManager` where ever is required. This need no extra configurations to do.
You can also go with Criteria's

Comment: No where in the JPARepository documentation they have mentioned about passing the dynamic queries. I think need to do some trick

Answer (score 2):

For Example If you want to find the Book based on combination of the attribute like authorName,title and cost then You can use the following query

`public interface BookQueryRepositoryExample extends Repository<Book, Long>
 {
       @Query(value = "select * from Book b where (?1 or null) and (?2 or null) and (?3 or null) ", 
        nativeQuery = true
)
    List<Book> findByWhatever(String authorName,String title,Double cost);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic where clauses using Specification interface that spring-data provides.

Here is a link for you: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 0):

> @Query(value = "select * from Book b where ?1", nativeQuery = true)
>   List findByWhatever(String qry);

First of all, your approach is not recommended and most likely will lead to **SQL injection vulnerability** (if you do not handle 'qry' parameter in a proper way).

**Secondly, you are trying to reinvent the wheel**. There are a lot of possible ways of implementing dynamic queries as @Jens Schauder has already mentioned in his answer. I will add one more way which seems to be the easiest one if you do not need complex stuff. It's called "[Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)".

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
}
```

Then you create an instance of an object that looks like those that you are trying to find, meaning that you have to set properties that you would use for a dynamic query generation:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setYear(2015);
book.setPublisher("O'Realy")

Example<Book> bookExample = Example.of(book);
```

The last step is to pass your example object to the Spring Data JPA repository:

```
List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll(bookExample);
```

As a result, you will get a list of books published in 2015 by O'Realy. The nice thing about it is that you can add more fields to search for in runtime just by setting it in `book` instance.

And if you need something more complex than match by exact values, you could use matchers. In the sample below Spring Data JPA will search for all books with a name starting with "O" ignoring case.

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setName("O")

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().
    .withMatcher("publisher", startsWith().ignoreCase());

Example<Book> bookExample = Example.of(book, matcher);

List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll(bookExample);
```