# MySql ANY_VALUE() method with CRUD repository

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default. So instead of disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY I am trying to use ANY_VALUE(arg)

The query fetches me the expected result.

I want this to be used with Spring Boot CrudRepository. So I had it on the **@Query** annotation something like below (just a sample). I want to use @Query annotation with a complex query

```
@Query("select any_value(c.id), c.number, any_value(c.type) from Call c group by c.number")
public List<Call> getCallsByType(Pageable pageable);
```

But it throws an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'any_value' {originalText=any_value}
 |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Did you try set [nativeQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949012/5594670) to true?

Comment: @Javvano Yes that works by setting nativeQuery to true. Thank you

Comment: `nativeQuery` absolutely defeats the purpose of JPA ... plus : native queries are the root of all evil. Do not use them. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tell Spring to treat that query as native one. Otherwise it will try to validate it according to the JPA specification.

Try:

```
@Query(value = "select any_value(c.id), c.number, any_value(c.type) from Call c group by c.number"
       , nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> getCallsByType(Pageable pageable);
```

Keep in mind that you cannot use the NEW operator syntax in this case and you would have to deal with result as an array of Object.

**Alternatively**

If you want to use map the results directly to a POJO class you would have to (assuming that you are using JPA 2.1+):

1) Define the mapping:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="resultMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=ResultClass.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                @ColumnResult(name="number")
                // further mappings ...
            }
        )
    }
)
```

2) Define a native query

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="getCallsByType"
    , query="select any_value(c.id), c.number, any_value(c.type) from Call c group by c.numbe")
```

3) Define this method in the CrudRepository without the `@Query` annotation:

```
public List<ResultClass> getCallsByType();
```