# How to fetch distinct list from SpringData without using query annotation?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I am using 2 different properties to fetch distinct list eg

`findDistinctBy<propertyName>And<propertyName>In(List<String> list)`.

My actual Spring jpa statement is

```
List<PojoClass> findAllByTpIdInAndDistinctMobile(List<String> edgeIds);
```

where TpId & Mobile are 2 different properties in PojoClass. I need to implement this without using Query annotation. Any suggestions of queryDsl will also do.

Comment: You can use projection or use Entity Manager to fetch data. You can view bellow thread to check possible solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945

Comment: The `findBy` methods are designed for simple cases, for more complex logic use `@Query` why jump through hoops if you can write a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be more clear.What exactly do you intend to achieve when the input is a list of Ids?

There is no option to provide a list to findAll unless it is an Id.
A simple way would be to loop the the input list in service and append the result to a result list.

```
for(String edgeId:edgeIds){
    resultList.addAll(findByEdgeId(edgeId));
}
```

Updated code after @Tejas comment

```
for(Pojo pojo:Pojos){
   resultList.addAll(findDistinctPojoByPropert1OrPropert2(String pojo.getProperty1(),String pojo.getProperty2());
}
```

Comment: I need to use Distinct & In JPA statement with 2 different pojo property, this need to be implemented without using @Query Annotation