# findById(ID) in CrudRepository - attempting to use incompatible return type

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data

I have defined message entity

```java
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @NotNull
    private User user;

    @NotEmpty(message = "text is required")
    private String text;

    @NotEmpty(message = "title is required")
    private String title;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and CrudRepository

```java
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {


    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'message')")
    Message findById(Long id);

    Iterable<Message> findByUserId(Long id);

    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'privateMessage')")
    Message findOne(Long id);

}
```

I get the following error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFC5e.png)

When I use

```java
 @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'message')")
  Optional<Message> findById(Long id);
```

still doesn't work.
I get, that the "Message message = messageRepository.findById(id);" cannot be converted and i should change  variable "message" type to the "Optional<"Message>"

When I do that, I get following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'defaultController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.chapter5.data.Message com.example.chapter5.data.MessageRepository.findOne(java.lang.Long)! No property findOne found for type Message!
```

Can someone suggest an alternative solution?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the `findOne` method or add an `@Query` to add the query. That simply doesn't work.

Comment: how are the methods `findById(Long id);` and `Message findOne(Long id);` different? what are you expecting from those two methods? seems same for me.(finding Message by its Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring data will convert your method names to actual database queries. But this doesn't happen magically. Of course spring does magic, But you have to follow the syntax.

In your first method, `Message findById(Long id);` Spring understands that you need Message object and you need to find that by message_id. This is converted it to somewhat like the following.

`select msg from Message msg where msg.id = ?1`;

`?1` will be replaced by your method argument.

If you do not wish Spring to generate the query for you, then you have to use `@Query` and provide your own custom query.(Method name does not matter in this case.)

you can achieve this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374883/query-annotation-with-custom-class-spring-boot-java).

Now, coming back to your error,
Spring is not able to understand your method `Message findOne(Long id);`.
Because it is expecting the syntax `findBy`.

You can find the valid method names from  [spring documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

What I don't understand is, how are methods  `Message findById(Long id);` and `Message findOne(Long id);` different. I suppose they both try to get Message from messageId.

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for your answer. Reply to your question: This serves to demonstrate two different rights as simply as possible. Messages found via `findById` can thus be viewed by the current user as well as by an administrator, while messages found via `findOne` can only be viewed by the current user.

Comment: Well in that case, I suggest having those authorizations on the service layer, rather than on the DAO layer. You really can't mess with method names while using spring data. Hope that helps

Comment: Even on DAO layer it boils down to to this. Both admin and current user can access `getMessageById`. Ex: admin and current user can access `X`, current user can also access `X`. This comes down to both admin and current user can access `X`.

Comment: Actually you have to annotate your repository interface with @Repository