# Injecting an EntityManager using @PersistenceContext

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We're currently using a problematic setup of our `EntityManager` like in the following. We'd like to change from `@PersistenceUnit` to `@PersistenceContext` for the entity mangager. How can we use the same `@Inject` mechanism?

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence-unit name="my-data-source" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/foo/model</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql:false}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**That's how we get the entity manager:**

```
@Stateless
public class EntityManagerProvider {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "my-data-source")
    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    @Produces
    @Default
    public EntityManager getDefaultEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

And within the application we inject the entity manager like this:

```
@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just call it like this, of course without calling EntityManagerFactory:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

In this case the container will handle the life cycle of the entity manager bean, so you don't need to call EntityManagerFactroy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is like bellow:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Here import's are given bellow :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
```

For more info, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945)