# How execute native SQL queries using Spring in runtime in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, nativequery

So, are there any methods to execute native SQL queries from `Repository` interface?

Yes, I know about `@Query` annotation, but how to execute queries that can be changed in runtime? Like in `JDBC` `executeQuery()` method?

Comment: Take a look at [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) class which is one of the primary JDBC integration points in Spring.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948795/is-it-possible-to-use-raw-sql-within-a-spring-repository

Answer (score 0):

Implement `JpaRepository` and use

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

to use the full power of Java to create `query` of type `string` and then:

```
 final Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query);
 final List<Object[]> resultList = emQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using Spring Data you could do something like :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p from Person p where r.name = :person_name")
Optional<Person> findPersonByName(@Param("person_name") String personName);
```

You can use native query as well :

```
@Query(value = "select * from person p where r.name = :person_name")", nativeQuery = true)
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Specification with your JpaRepository to make a dynamic query built at runtime.

Add JpaSpecificationExecutor to your JpaRepository interface...

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
}
```

Then make a class with a static method that returns a Specification....

```
public class MyEntitySearchSpec {
  private MyEntitySearchSpec() {
    // Remove this private constructor if need to add public non-static methods.
  }

  public static Specification<MyEntity> myEntitySearch(
      final mysearchCriteria MySearchCriteria) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
      List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

      if (mysearchCriteria.isOnlyActive()) {
        predicates.add(cb.isNull(root.get("closeDate")));
      }

      if (mysearchCriteria.getCaseNumber() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("caseNumber"),
            mysearchCriteria.getCaseNumber()));
      }

      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
    };
  }
}
```

The you can call like this...

```
myRepo.findAll(myEntitySearch(mysearchCriteria));
```