# The column name XYZ was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a native query in spring boot. (shown below) . This is sowing me error "The column name seq_id was not found in this ResultSet.". But when Iam removing distinct and putting * then the result is coming. Here seq_id is a sequence here.

```
@Query(value = " SELECT DISTINCT DEPOT FROM  {h-schema}mt_schedule_task where schedule_name=? AND department=? ", nativeQuery=true)
```

Comment: What's the object for this querying result? An entity? Or a String?

Comment: Please show us the method signature

Comment: it is done now. It was entity . Now I changed to String. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think "DEPOT" is a column name.Commonly native query only return object.

Check this one [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948795/is-it-possible-to-use-raw-sql-within-a-spring-repository/37212043#37212043)