# JPA, @Transient field and Native Query mapping

Tags: java, jpa, nativequery

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entry")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "viewEntry",
    entities =
    @EntityResult(entityClass = ViewEntry.class,
            fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name="id", column = "id"),
                    @FieldResult(name="guid", column = "guid"),
                    @FieldResult(name="link", column = "link"),
                    @FieldResult(name="descr", column = "descr"),
                    @FieldResult(name="pubDate", column = "pub_date"),
                    @FieldResult(name="read", column = "my_read")
            }
    )
)
public class ViewEntry implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String guid;
    private String link;
    private String descr;
    private Date pubDate;
    @Transient
    private Boolean read;
}
```

The field `read` resides in another table, So I made it transient, to prevent JPA mapping errors. To retrieve entity's content I want to use native query that looks like this:

```
select id,guid,link,descr,pub_date,feed_id,user_id,is_read as my_read from entry join user_to_entry ....
-- skipped dynamic part of query
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to map native queries to my entity. In particular I don't know if the @Transient field will be ignored by EntityManager. Help, please.

Comment: May be a typo, but you in your mapping you specify column as `my_read` but in the query it is called `is_read`.

Comment: As I understand the `column` parameter is the name of alias in the resultset, the `name` parameter is the field's name. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You're right, it's just there wasn't `as my_read` in the original post.

Comment: @PredragMaric my mistake. Posted outdated sql. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map results of a native query you can use SqlResultSetMapping
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html

Without a mapping if the columns in the native query matches the attribute name or if they are mapped with @Column in the Entity then you don't need a mapping.

Comment: Will the transient field be filled with value in case of such mapping? I tried it before and got nulls in `read` field.

Comment: look at my edited question to see SqlResultSetMapping I tried to use

Comment: Transient fields @Transient and transient (Java key word) will always be ignored by JPA!

Comment: Too bad. What can I do to fill that field?

Comment: Do you really need ViewEntry as an Entity? Means do you want to save and delete? Otherwise you had the possibility to use the ConstructorExpression to create DTOs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor

Comment: since I use native query(i.e. plain SQL, not JPQL), the ConstructorExpression is unavailable to me.

Comment: In the process some other issues appeared, so I had to map my entities little bit different. As to this question I ended with manual object creation using array result from query.getResultList(). Thanks to everyone who participated.

Answer (score 3):

You can map the field in another table by using [`@SecondaryTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) in your entity. Something like this:

```
...
@SecondaryTable(name="user_to_entry", 
        pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="entry_id"))
public class ViewEntry implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String guid;
    private String link;
    private String descr;
    @Column(name="pub_date")
    private Date pubDate;
    @Column(table = "user_to_entry")
    private Boolean read;
}
```

If you can't do that for some reason, you can map the native SQL results to entity like this

```
em.createNativeQuery("<native SQL>", ViewEntry.class)
```

but I don't think this will map a transient field (I could be wrong, haven't tested it).

Third option is to use `@SqlResultSetMapping`, but I'm also not sure this will work with transient fields. Check [this](http://javaee.support/sample/jpa-native-sql-resultset-mapping/) for an example.

Comment: I can't use @SecondaryTable because it only accepts keys as mapping columns. I tried that.

Comment: What I do now is : `Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), "viewEntry");` where `viewEntry` is name of @SqlResultSetMapping.

Comment: I have no Idea. If I remove @Transient annotation ORM will fail to find corresponding column in table. Maybe there is a way to disable this check and allow named query to map this field?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. So, just to be clear, `@Transient` field isn't filled when mapped in `@SqlResultSetMapping`?

Comment: Yes, I got nulls in all objects I retrieve.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21487061/4074715), Manual Mapping part, it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, you can create a view with your join and map your view like a normal table. You just need to delete that new table that hibernate will create for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp