# How to map a Native Query to a POJO, when I do not have any Entity on my project?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am translating an ETL process from a tool to a Java batch API application. In this ETL process. In the current version (using the tool) we have many SQL statements that join different tables in order to generate the desired output. Translating to Java, JPA is now available.

I would like to use native queries. This would be nice because it would not require creating entities for every table used in the query and I could use POJOs for the result of the queries (also, I would not need to rewrite the queries). Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection/21487061#21487061) I know I could use `@SqlResultSetMapping`. The problem is that I do not have any entity in my project, so I do not know where to put this annotation. Is there anywhere I can put this annotation so the entity manager finds it?

PS: in my proof of concepts I am currently manually converting from an array of objects to the POJO, but I really don't like this approach.

Adding the `@Entity` annotation to the POJO will cause my application not to start:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: MyTable

I am not sure (searching for it right now), but I think it could be caused by this property in my persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

Comment: All in all, using an ORM suggests that you want to deal with an object model (expressed in terms of JPA) and not with a data model directly (expressed in terms of RDBMS). As such, why do you hesitate in creating entities based on your data model? Using native query unnecessarily everywhere simply implies that you are not dealing much with an ORM that you need to do to avail of an ORM at a maximum extent. Native queries are to be used only when they are absolutely needed (BTW, `@SqlResultSetMapping` is a feature of JPA 2.1 (Hibernate 4.3.0 and onwards) and not available in previous versions).

Comment: True. The issue is that I am migrating an ETL system, so I have the following arguments not to use JPA to the maximum extent: 1-I do have many complex queries that are already written, 2-I deal with 2 databases, but only a relatively small set of tables for each one of them, 3-I have almost no business logic at all, just data manipulation. This makes me lean towards the idea that I should not use JPA at a maximum extent, but only where I profit the most from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I found the [answer I was looking for](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/):

I can define `@SqlResultSetMapping`'s behavior using XML in orm.xml, so this definition:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "BookValueMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = BookValue.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "version", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "authorName")}))
```

Would be defined in XML like this:

```
<sql-result-set-mapping name="BookValueMappingXml">
    <constructor-result target-class="org.thoughts.on.java.jpa.value.BookValue">
        <column name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <column name="title"/>
        <column name="version" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <column name="authorName"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

Allowing me to do define it without needing an entity.

Comment: Hey boss, I am trying to use this but I am unable to understand where can I use this annotation? I am trying to use this annotation for the dao method where I am using to call this native query and I am getting a compilation error saying that this is not the correct location to use this annotation. Could you please help me the correct location to use this annotation? I tried using this annotation for my dao class and then also getting a compilation error as attribute classes is undefined for this annotation. Thanks in advance for your help on this

Comment: Use it on an EntityClass

Answer (score 5):

You can map native sql to POJO using JPA.  The POJO just needs @Entity and a @Id.  A simple example:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TodoQueryModel {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TodoQueryModel [id=" + id + ", description=" + description
            + "]";
    }
}
```

Some method in your JPA impl:

```
private void queryWithNativeSQL() {
    List<TodoQueryModel> todoList = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT id, description FROM [whatever you want as long as it returns 'id' and 'description' as column names]", TodoQueryModel.class)
        .setParameter(1, "foobar");
        .getResultList();

    for (TodoQueryModel todo : todoList) {
        System.out.println(todo);
    }

    System.out.println("Size: " + todoList.size());
}
```

You can also use @Column(name="barfoo") to map columns to attributes who's names don't match.

The @Id column needs to uniquely identify the instance in the JPA context.

Comment: Ok, but then I need a table corresponding to this "pojo" (entity), right?

Comment: No, JPA will map the columns returned from your native SQL into the columns of the "Entity".  As long as you're not calling EntityManager merge, persist, remove etc. there is no need for a db table for your Entity.

I've used this technique for retrieving different "Views" of my data that are table mapped by other JPA entities in the system.  The down side is, it's using native sql.  The up side is, I control the SQL and join where they're most efficient.

Comment: Cool! I will try it out tomorrow and get back to you :)

Comment: Doing that I get: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: MyTable (I am adding this info to the question)

Answer (score 1):

In the past (before JPA) we used iBatis as ORM tool (now called Mybatis). I'm still a big fan of it because you have a lot of flexibility in the way to write your SQL. You can really optimize your queries, espacially if **you** want to decide in which order joins are executed. All SQL statements and mappings (columns to POJO and vice-versa) are done in XML file. In the current version it is also possible to use annotations I think like you would to with JPA.

More info: http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/

Comment: I can't change the current provider (hibernate) and I should use the JPA specification standards ;)

Comment: I was confused by your sentence: "JPA is not available". But it seams you do have JPA. Sorry, can't help you any further.

Comment: Sorry! It was a typo, my bad! It was meant to be "JPA is NOW available"