# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: New Object. JTA

Tags: java, jpa, jta

Due the complexity of my dataBase, i decided create a new Object where I specifying just the parameters that I will to use. To do custom query I'm using createNativeQuery in JPA. Following my Object.

POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Unidade implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Long numeroUnidade;
    private String nomeUnidade;
    private Integer numeroCep;
    private Integer numeroCepComplemento;
    private String tipoServico;
    private Integer status;
    private String logradouro;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;
    private Integer statusVinculo; 

   //getter and setters
```

Currently I'm using the following select to return the simple integer and works without show any problem.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="projetoAtividade")
private EntityManager em;

public void selectTeste(){
        int quantidade = (Integer) em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from abc.nattbu29_escritorio;").getSingleResult();
        System.out.println("========== QUANTIDADE DE REGISTRO NA TABELA ===========");
        System.out.println(quantidade);
    }
```

Although the previous query worked fine, when a submit a complex query putting the respective alias, using too createNativeQuery and putting the object return, the hibernate throw a exception (org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown).

Remembering that I create a new class putting @Entity specifying.

Query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<UnidadeTeste> buscarUnidadeGenerica(int numeroCeps, int numeroComplementoCeps){
            List<UnidadeTeste> lsita = new ArrayList<UnidadeTeste>();
            String query = "SELECT "
                    +"TBZ21.NATURAL as numeroPv, "
                    +"TBZ21.UNIDADE as nomePv, "
                    +"TBZ21.SITUACAO as statusVinculacao, "
                    +"TBJ55.TPO_ATUACAO_U44 as tipoServAZW, "
                    +"TBJ55.SITUACAO_ATUAL as status, "
                    +"TBH18.LOCALIDADE as cidade, "
                    +"'' as bairro, "
                    +"'' as logradouro, "
                    +"TBH18.CEP as numeroCep, "
                    +"TBH18.CEP_COMPLEMENTO as numeroCepComplemento, "
                    +"TBH18.FK_AZWVWL22_UNISG as uf "
                    +"FROM AZW.AZWTBJ55_RGATUACAO TBJ55 "
                    +"LEFT JOIN AZW.AZWTBH18_LOCALIDADE TBH18 ON "
                    +"TBH18.LOCALIDADEE = TBJ55.LOCALIDADEE "
                    +"LEFT JOIN AZW.AZWTBZ21_UNIDADE TBZ21 ON "
                    +"TBJ55.NATURAL = TBZ21.NATURAL "
                    +"WHERE TBH18.CEP = ?1 "
                        +"AND TBH18.CEP_COMPLEMENTO = ?2; "

            lsita = em.createNativeQuery(query, Unidade.class)
                    .setParameter(1, numeroCeps)
                    .setParameter(2, numeroComplementoCeps)
                    .getResultList();
            System.out.println(lsita.size()+"<<<<=====================");
            return lsita;
        }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: br.com.project.modelo.UnidadeTeste
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1031) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:336) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:377) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:356) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:172) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:87) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:218) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:224) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 84 more
```

In my search through the internet, almost all forum topics was unanimous in the solution answer: " Put the @Entity before class declaration" but, it not works to me.

I had "spent" all my day trying looking for a solutions worked but, unfortunately, 
I not had successes. Someone can say a new way to solve my problem?
I tested in 2 different project and hapens the same problem.

**Question complement:**

Folks, I tried create a @SqlResultSetMapping into my class, the coding following, but now, the hibernate trows the another exception:

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--127.0.0.1-8888-2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component AtividadeEJB for method public void br.com.project.jboss.modelo.AtividadeEJB.testeChamada(): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [UnidadeResult]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
```

My new POJO:

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="UnidadeResult", 
entities={ 
    @EntityResult(entityClass=UnidadeTeste.class, fields={
        @FieldResult(name="tx_descricao", column="nomePv"),
        @FieldResult(name="nu_idntr_pessoa", column="id")})},
columns={
    @ColumnResult(name="nomePv")}
)


public class UnidadeTeste implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String nomePv;

    public String getNomePv() {
        return nomePv;
    }

    public void setNomePv(String nomePv) {
        this.nomePv = nomePv;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

My EJB:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testeChamada(){
        List<Object> lista = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT nu_idntr_pessoa as id, email as nomePv FROM pessoa;", "UnidadeResult").getResultList();
        System.out.println("===============>>"+lista.size());
    }
```

Comment: Can you check in your entity class that you have imported  `javax.persistence.Entity` instead of `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` and did you make JPA aware of this entity through mapping tag of `persistence.xml` or `component-scan` etc

Comment: So, I'm using just `javax.persistence.Entity` into my project. I believe that this problem not happened for this reason. Now a new error happens after implements SqlResultSetMapping. Do you know if i need some special library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to return a native query's results to an object I would suggest using [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html).

Otherwise, set your return type to:

```
List<Object[]> results = em.createNativeQuery(query)
                .setParameter(1, numeroCeps)
                .setParameter(2, numeroComplementoCeps)
                .getResultList();
```

And then loop through the result list, and cast each member of the Object array to its data type.

Comment: I have improve my question, putting new result of my test applying your suggestion of using SqlResultSetMapping and putting the resultList into a generic Object list but dont works too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

List<**UnidadeTeste**> lsita = new ArrayList<**UnidadeTeste**>();

lsita = em.createNativeQuery(query, **Unidade**.class)

There is a type mismatch here. The exception is clear : Unknown entity: br.com.project.modelo.**UnidadeTeste**

Your entity is Unidade and you must so return a `List<Unidade>` not `UnidadeTeste`.

Otherwise try [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

Comment: It was my fault but even fix this code part, don't works yet. I have improve my question, putting new result of my test applying your suggestion of using SqlResultSetMapping but dont works too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

In this topic:[How to map a Native Query to a POJO, when I do not have any Entity on my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595445/how-to-map-a-native-query-to-a-pojo-when-i-do-not-have-any-entity-on-my-project)
are describe exactly my problem. But even reading before, I could not understand a little detail, that solved my problem.

Even creating a simple entity for receiver a result of my query, is necessary to map my class into persistence.xml. this was my mistake!

So, my project now:

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="projetoAtividade" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/projetoAtividade</jta-data-source>

        //another classes

        <class>br.com.project.modelo.UnidadeTeste</class>

        //properties of connection
```

UnidadeTeste.class:

```
package br.com.project.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UnidadeTeste {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

EJB:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testeChamada(){
        List<UnidadeTeste> lista = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT nu_idntr_pessoa AS id, email AS description FROM Pessoa", UnidadeTeste.class).getResultList();
        System.out.println("===============>>"+lista.size());
    }
```

Remember that you need put aliases for column with the same name on attributes that you created in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a SqlResultSetMapping annotation as well and refer to it in your named native query annotation:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "nameToReferTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = X.class,
                columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "A"), @ColumnResult(name = "B")})
)
```