# JPA - Casting @OneToMany field from Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have @Entity, which looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Plane {

  @Id
  private Long planeid;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Passenger.class, cascade ={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "planeid")
  private List<Passenger> passengers;

...
```

I am using such method in interface extending JPARepository:

```
@Transactional
public interface PlaneRepository extends JpaRepository<Plane, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM planes p JOIN passengers v USING(planeid) WHERE v.name = 'Carlos' GROUP BY p.planeid", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Plane> findAllPlanesMatching();

}
```

As a result of this method I get list of all plane objects, which have passenger with name 'Carlos', but inside of every plane object List contains list of all passenger, but I would like this list have only passengers called 'Carlos'. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two modes: entity mapping and native query mapping. Native query you use does not work directly with entity mapping. Look at this discussion: [JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection)

In your case, I don't see why you can't use JPA all way through with JPQL queries.

You need to map a `@ManyToOne` relationship in the `Passenger` class

```
@ManyToOne
private Plane plane;
```

and run this query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Passenger p WHERE p.name = :name")
            .setParameter("name", "Carlos")
            .getResultList();
```

You will get only passenger matching the name Carlos, and you can access their planes traversing `p.getPlane()`.