# JPA Native Query with call to Oracle function returns the same object in different calls in same Transaction context

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, jakarta-ee, caching

I'm having a problem regarding the execution of a query in a managed transaction context (Using JTA Transaction Factory)

During the entire execution of the request the query should be executed twice: the first time fetching default values from database; the second time, run with different parameters, it should return a different object with different values.

The query itself makes a call to a function in an Oracle database like this:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3
FROM TABLE(package.function (
    param1 => :param1,
    param2 => :param2,
    param3 => :param3))
```

The method which does the query (and which must be executed twice with different parameters) is something like:

```
public MyEntity getMyEntity(Map<String,String> params) {
    String sql = getQuery(); // gets the string of the aforementioned query
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql, MyEntity.class);

    query.setParameter("param1", params.get("param1"));
    query.setParameter("param2", params.get("param2"));
    query.setParameter("param3", params.get("param3"));

    return (MyEntity) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

The problem is that during the execution of the request, the first time this method gets called, it returns a certain `MyEntity` object which is correct. However, the second time the function gets called, the function `getMyEntity` wrongly returns the very same object (his Java Object reference is the same of the first object's), although the parameters with which it gets called are different.

It seems like a caching problem; so I explicitly added to my `persistence.xml` file the following properties

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
```

and set a query hint

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.CACHEABLE, false);
```

but the problem still remains.

I would like to ask if I am missing something and if there is a way of solving this problem.

Note: the code is part of a project which is a porting of an old application to a new version based on RESTful Apis, so changing the logic structure of the code is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA specification forces

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql, MyEntity.class);
```

To return managed instances of MyEntity.  You are causing the MyEntity instance to be built by the first query to be managed and tracked for changes, and of course, its identity will be managed.  Once an entity is loaded, that same instance is returned every time you query for that instance.  So when your next query returns a row with similar ID values, the previous entity is returned instead.

Some options, depending on your provider are:

1. clear the cache.  Calling em.clear() might help if you are in a
   transaction, otherwise you may need to evict the entity from the
   shared cache.
2. force a refresh.  EclipseLink has a refresh query
   hint that if used on the second query, will cause the entity to be
   reloaded with the second set of data
3. Do not use managed entities
   for functions that are better suited for raw data.  If all you want
   is a DTO for the data, use the constructor option as outlined
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection)

Option 3 makes much more sense to me, as there is less risk of corrupting the cache and objects returned from other queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Option 1 worked perfectly for me, effectively deleting the cache. I have not tried the other two approaches because I'm trying to conform to the old legacy code without changing too much of the structure.