# JPA Entity mapped by SQL Join Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0

I want to create an entity `ReportEntry` which is mapped by an SQL. Here are two tables - `user` and `group`.

```
mysql> desc user;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| active                 | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| language               | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activationDate         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| group_id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
|                                                                               |
|                           ...More columns...                                  |
|                                                                               |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc group;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| displayName                | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am joining these tables on `group_id` using the below SQL query.

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN group g ON u.group_id = g.id
```

For the above query, I want to create an Entity and use the above SQL query as its mapping. How can I achieve this?

I don't want just the mapping, but I also want to use the entity to be able to query for records as well. For example, let's say I am able to create the mapping with entity, `RecordEntry`, I should be able to get a specific record with query like `FROM RecordEntry WHERE id = :id" and I will pass`id```` as parameter. That way the final query should get executed in native form would be like(for id=1).

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN group g ON u.group_id = g.id AND id = 1
```

Comment: can you please provide an example of the result of this query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection)

Comment: @nezdolik, I have updated my question to give more details as I need an entity which I can query in JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping the result to a POJO, I would suggest creating entities for both classes and mapping them with the one to one annotation JPA provides:

```
@Entity
public class User{
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")
  private Group group;
  ...
}


@Entity
public class Group{
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
}
```

Update to reflect updated question:
You could then use e.g. the Criteria-API (or named queries), to query these entities:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root user = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(user.get("id"), criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class, "id")));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter("id", id);
User result = (User)query.getSingleResult();
```

[Source: Wikibooks on JPA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria)

Comment: This solution is more elegant than simply creating an "all fields" POJO, because it reflects the proper association hierarchy between Users and the Group they belong to. Likewise, all User and Group attributes are still easily accessible.

Comment: Yep. Finally did via the mappings into two classes as you suggested.