# Need to use bitwise"&" operator in JPA2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to convert the below condition in JPA2,but found there is no alternative to Apply a constraint expressed in SQL with no JDBC parameters

Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.col3& " + value + " = " + value);

I tried using NativeQuery like the below sinppet where value is the parameter passing to the method:-

```
String sqlString="select * from myTable where col1=3600 and col2=true and col3&"+value+"="+value;
        Query query=getSession().createNativeQuery(sqlString);
        List<userDefClass> results = new ArrayList<userDefClass>();
        results=(List<userDefClass>)query.getResultList();
```

For the above logic ,I am getting below error:-

"java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.pkg.userDefClass java.lang.RuntimeException

query.getResultList() is passing list of objects but not list of userdefClass objects.

ALso I tried using Typed Query but it is throwing SQL Grammer Exception.I guess its not parsing the bitwise '&' operator in the SQL String.

Please help.

Comment: You can't cast the the result list like that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection) answer on how to map a result set in JPA, I think that might set you on the right course.

Comment: Thanks..let me go through the link...hope it helps

Comment: Tried a lot,still getting SQL Grammer Exception as it is not able to  understand the bitwise operator '&' in the native SQL query.

Comment: Below is the link if someone is looking for answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/44045138/8014983

Answer (score 0):

please Try  this :

```
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(userDefClass.class));
```

Comment: setResultTransformer is deprecated method in JPA 2.1