# Predicate for bitwise '&' operator check in where clause in JPA2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to put a condition for bitWise operator '&' in SQl where clause, using JPA2 which returns a predicate.

Comment: JPQL doesn't support such operators. The only persistence standard allowing that is JDO, and its query language JDOQL. If using JPA you would have to use native queries

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am  using HIbernate with JPA. there are many complex queries with many table joins.Writing proper native SQL query will be  difficult. Trying to do something like this                                               EntityManager em = this.getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserDefClass> query = builder.createQuery(UserDefClass.class);
predicates.add(builder.equal(***NEED to add constraint here which accepts bitwise (&) operator*****)))));
query.select(UserDefClass).where(predicates)
;

Comment: You can't do that with Criteria so don't waste your time

Comment: Thanks.I took your advice and used Native queries in combination with MySQLDialect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996494/predicate-for-bitwise-operator-check-in-where-clause-in-jpa2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create a NamedQuery/NativeQuery
2.Create a class  MySQLDialect which extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

```
public class MySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect {
    public MySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("bitwiseAnd", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BIG_INTEGER,
                "(?1 & ?2)"));
    }
```

3.Make sure you place te below statement in your "hibernate.cfg.xml"

**com.Mypackage.MySQLDialect**

4.In your dao class you can call the above "bitwiseAnd" method like below

```
TypedQuery<UserDefClass> q = em.createNamedQuery("YOUR NativeQuery name", UserDefClass.class);
        q.setParameter(0, value);
        q.setParameter(1, new BigInteger(value));
        List<UserDefClass> list = q.getResultList();
```

Hope this helps someone.I hope hibernate-JPA community adds inbuilt help for bitwise operators as well.