# Mapping SQL results to Java models

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, model, dao

Let's say I have these tables:

TABLE A

```
col_a |
-----
a1
....
```

TABLE B

```
col_b | col_c | amount
---------------------
a1    | b1    | 2.2
a1    | b2    | 4.5
```

TABLE C

```
col_d
----
b1 
b2
....
```

All these tables have associated models within Java.

Now what I would like is the following:

```
col_a | b2 |  ....
------------
a1    | 4.5 |(from tableB.amount)
.....
```

The query I have now is this;

```
SELECT a.col_a,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.col_d = 'b1' THEN b.amount end) AS 'Kcal',
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.col_d = 'b2' THEN b.amount end) AS 'Kjoule',
  .... etc
    FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.col_b = a.col_a
    LEFT JOIN tableC c ON b.col_c = c.col_d
      GROUP BY a.col_a;
```

which results in something like this:

```
col_a | Kcal | Kjoule
---------------------
a1    | amount | amount
```

This ResulSet is exactly what I need, but I can't map this to my models in Java. How can I use this ResultSet to model it in Java, or should I use a different approach?

Comment: Hi Mees refer to below link may be helpful. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection)

Comment: @MdShareef I'm not using JPA for this project.

Comment: You have to do mapping from ResultSet to JAVA object by using getXXX() functions in ResultSet

Comment: @Tuco How could I keep the relations they have in the above result if I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another entity (model) with your fields, something like:

```
public class Result{
  private String col;
  private BigDecimal kcal;
  private BigDecimal kjoule;
  ...
  getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of this aswell, is this the preffered way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it's preffered way but it could be a solution. It also depend of your project's best practice.