# Map result of sql query to DTO object(which has inner list)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following SQL query

```
SELECT
  customer.CUSTOMER_NUMBER customerNumber,
  contractDetail.START_DATE campaignStartDate,
  contractDetail.END_DATE  campaignEndDate,
  contractDetailCommitment.END_DATE  commitmentEndDate,
  contractDetail.CONTRACT_DETAIL_STATUS statusCode,
  baseOffer.NAME campaignName,
  property.CODE propertyCode,
  DECODE(property.TYPE, 'LOV', propertyListChoice.CODE, assetPropertyValue.PROPERTY_VALUE) propertyValue
FROM .............
```

The query structure is not important, it returns data like this

[image]

So, different values only in two fields: propertyCode and propertyValue. I want to map the result of this query to following dto object:

```
@Data
public class ContractInfoDTO {
    private String customerNumber;
    private String campaignStartDate;
    private String campaignEndDate;
    private String campaignName;
    private String statusCode;
    private List<Property> properties;
}
```

Is it possible to do that automatically? Or the only solution is to write custom `ResultTransformer` and handle all three rows one by one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection

Comment: To which fields of `ContractInfoDTO` class would you like to map `propertyCode` and `propertyValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `JPA` you can map query result directly into DTO, for example

```
SELECT new com.company.MyDTO(p.someField, p.someField2...)
```

But firstly you need to transform your `SQL` query to `JPQL` query.

Comment: And then the result will always be Collection<MyDTO> resultSet. Also MyDTO should provide the respective constructor definition.

Comment: That's right. Constructor must much fields that you want to map.

Comment: same result could be achieved by using this very same native query. Just it's recommended to use JPQL  whenever it's possible.