# Not able to get array object response in @Query annotation in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto, jsonresult, nativequery

My Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TestNativeQRepository extends CrudRepository<TestNativeQ, String> {

    @Query( value="SELECT qplt.name price_list_name,  qplab.status_code, qplab.start_date, (SELECT charge_definition_code FROM oalfsaas_repl.QP_CHARGE_DEFINITIONS_B WHERE charge_definition_id=qplab.charge_definition_id  ) chargedefinitioncode "
                + "FROM  pricelistsall qplab, PRICELISTSTL qplt "
                + " WHERE qplab.price_list_id  =qplt.price_list_id ", nativeQuery = false)
    public List<TestNativeQDTO> getAllDetails();
}
```

Actual Result:

```
[{"ABC", "DEF", "15/05/2018", "XXZ"}]
```

Expected Result

```
[{name: "ABC", statuscode: "DEF", startDate: "15/05/2018", chargedefintioncode: "XXZ"}]
```

Comment: The result of native query is not automatically transformed to an Entity, you must do it manually or define mappings via `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@ColumnResult`. Refer this question for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko thanks for the correcting

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. What if nativeQuery = false and columns are from more than 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

As @Nikolay gave hint in comment.

*The result of native query is not automatically transformed to an Entity, you must do it manually or define mappings via @SqlResultSetMapping and @ColumnResult.*

to make that work follow the below code.

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "someName", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = SamplePojo.class), columns = @ColumnResult(name = "columnName"))
public class SamplePojo{
//fields and getters/setters
}
```

and Then in query

```
List<SamplePojo> list = entityManager().createNativeQuery("Select ......", "someName").getResultList();
```

Note  : `someName` should be same in both places.

Refer [this-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection)

Comment: Hi, Is there any blog respected to it ?

Comment: My hint was related to using native queries in repo methods denoted with `@Query`. If you use EntityManager directly then following should be enough: 
`List<SamplePojo> list = entityManager().createNativeQuery("Select ......", SamplePojo.class).getResultList();` (without extra mappings)