# ConverterNotFoundException:from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [com.spacestudy.model.DeptListForJointusePer]

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am using PostgreSQL. In that I created a function. I want to call that function into service method.I created repository for that function using native query. But I am unable to get the result which I get when running the function in PostgreSQL db. I get exception like "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [com.spacestudy.model.DeptListForJointusePer]".

**Model:**

```
@Entity
public class DeptListForJointusePer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    public Integer p_nDeptID;
    @Column
    public Integer res_salaryPercent;
    @Column
    public Integer res_nClientCPCMappingId;
    @Column
    public String res_CPCCODE ; 
    @Column
    public String res_sDeptName ; 
    @Column
    public String res_sClientDeptId ; 
    @Column
    @JsonProperty(value = "text")
    public String res_sAlternateJointUsePercentage;

        //getters and setters
```

**Repository:**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from GetDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages(:p_nInstID,:p_nDeptID)")
    List<DeptListForJointusePer> getDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages(@Param("p_nInstID")Integer p_nInstID,@Param("p_nDeptID") Integer p_nDeptID);
```

**Service:**

```
public List<DeptListForJointusePer>  getDeptListForViewModifyJoinyusePer(Integer p_nInstID,Integer p_nDeptID) {

        List<DeptListForJointusePer> result = roomDeptMapRepoObj.getDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages(p_nInstID, p_nDeptID);
        return result;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/function")
    public List<DeptListForJointusePer>  function(@RequestParam(value="p_nInstID",required=true)Integer p_nInstID
                                                 ,@RequestParam(value="p_nDeptID",required=true)Integer p_nDeptID){
        return roomDeptMapServiceObj.getDeptListForViewModifyJoinyusePer(p_nInstID, p_nDeptID);

    }
```

**error:**

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.spacestudy.model.DeptListForJointusePer] for value '{21714, 12.50000000000000000000, 7, IDR, Electron Microscopy Resource Center, 111070, YES}';
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [com.spacestudy.model.DeptListForJointusePer]
```

Comment: Try `SELECT  * FROM function()` form...

Comment: BTW, how is the stored function's return type declared?

Comment: I already tried that, then  it gives error like org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException

Comment: I declared function return type like RETURNS Table(values...).

Comment: Hmmm... Is `DeptListForJointusePer` mapped as entity?

Comment: That is not an entity ,it's a simple input class.

Comment: Then how could JPA convert the data from the `ResultSet` into instances of that class?

Comment: That class is not present in db.That i created for only returning result.What i need to do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013323/4899193

Comment: I didn't got any ans from given link. Because the given solution also uses entity class.Can anyone tell what exactly i am doing wrong or need to change?

Comment: Should annotate your model class as `@Entity @SqlResultsetMapping`, and Spring/JPA should pick it up...

Comment: Or even just `@Entity`...

Comment: should i need to create table or without table in db can i use @entity ?

Comment: If you do not add `@Table` then you do not need a table in the db...

Comment: I added @Entity ,@SqlResultsetMaping but i am getting error like org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [com.spacestudy.model.DeptListForJointusePer]

Comment: Hmm, it says it cannot convert `BigDecimal` to your entity... Maybe my 1st advice of using the `SELECT * FROM fn()` form was not the right one, try the original form of `SELECT fn()`...

Comment: If i use original form of select fn() i am getting that same previous error :No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: can you tell why this error generates?