# JPA native query return type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have the following query

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select systimestamp from dual",
                    Timestamp.class);
```

However, I get the error

```
Missing descriptor for [class java.sql.Timestamp].
```

How do I return type of `Timestamp` or `Date` from the native query?

Comment: post the whole stacktrace, as well as more code

Comment: post also your JPA version and have a look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection