# Converting a native query result having NULL values to a POJO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented the solution from this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013323/10944013

The solution only works for the native query results having non null values. 
I have described a case where this solution fails

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="POJOClassMapping",
classes={
      @ConstructorResult
      (    
        targetClass=POJOClass.class,
        columns= {
                @ColumnResult(name="name", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="marks", type=int.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="DateOFBirth", type=String.class)
               }
      )
    }
)


public class POJOClass
{
    private String name;

    private int marks;

    private String DateOFBirth;

    public POJOClass()
    {
    }

    public POJOClass(String name, int marks, String dateOFBirth) {

        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
        DateOFBirth = dateOFBirth;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getDateOFBirth() {
        return DateOFBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOFBirth(String dateOFBirth) {
        DateOFBirth = dateOFBirth;
    }

}
```

My table looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+-------------+---------+
| Name    | Marks | DateOFBirth | RollNum |
+---------+-------+-------------+---------+
| SomeXYZ | 10    | Null        | 36      |
| SomeQWE | 20    | 01-3-1990   | 43      |
+---------+-------+-------------+---------+
```

my query is

```
select name,marks,dateOfBirth from myTable where name = "SomeXYZ"
```

The dateOfBirth in this case has a null value. Because of which I've been getting the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null`. As the POJO class constructor with arguments has one of the argument null. Below is the exception thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.extract(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:761) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at com.manh.optimizationportal.LoadAnalyzerCommon.LoadAnalyzerCommonRepository.GetLARecCustCommmitData(LoadAnalyzerCommonRepository.java:69) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.manh.optimizationportal.LoadAnalyzerCommon.LoadAnalyzerCommonRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7fd38196.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.manh.optimizationportal.LoadAnalyzerCommon.LoadAnalyzerCommonRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f35b549.GetLARecCustCommmitData(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.manh.optimizationportal.LoadAnalyzerCommon.LoadAnalyzerCommonService.getLARecCustCommmitData(LoadAnalyzerCommonService.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.manh.optimizationportal.LoadAnalyzerCommon.LoadAnalyzerCommonController.getBookedOutCount(LoadAnalyzerCommonController.java:51) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Add your @SqlResultSetMapping

Comment: @AdyJunior I have edited the post.

Comment: I tried to find the error, but I couldn't. Its very crazy.... So, try change marks ocurrences types -> type=int.class to type=Integer.class and change "int marks" to "Integer marks", in constructor and in field type. The other way to throw that exception is when cast Date to String. Then try change dateOfBirth type from String to Date, in the same way that I told above about marks filed.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the same error?

Comment: @AdyJunior I tried changing the data types still no use.

Comment: Try to make int an Integer in your POJO and in the resultsetmapping

Comment: I tried it still no use.As @AdyJunior had mentioned earlier.

Comment: @SrihariUttanur, I don able reproduce the same error. How would you upload your code to a repository?

Comment: I was having multiple int fields where I was getting NULLs. Changing all of them to Integer worked. Thanks for the help. Please make sure to post the answer so that I'll accept it.

Comment: add `RollNum` to POJO class

Comment: Since my query result doesn't have RollNum I will get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class throwing the error indicates this is not a JPA/Hibernate issue in particular but a general Java issue when creating runtime instance. For the code and logs above it seems you are trying this

> Integer(null) -> int

casting a null `Integer` instance to a primitive `int`. This would have worked if it was a non-null value because Java does the [unboxing](http://rg.hibernate.HibernateException:%20Unable%20to%20call%20class) for you. But since it is a null value Java cannot cast it into primitive `int`. Therefore, it is giving an `IllegalArgumentException`. There can be other user cases as well for this exception to occur for `SqlResultSetMapping` columns. To avoid this

- Explicity mention the type e.g `@ColumnResult(name = "count", type = Integer.class`
- For POJO fields use Class(Integer) and not primitive(int).

Comment: Actually I posted comments saying this was the problem. Thanks for posting this.