# JSON response and POJO have column names with different case

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The fields have a mismatch in their case. I feel that I'm missing something when the POJO fields are converted to JSON response. The Jackson serialization is not setting the properties correctly

```
My JSON response looks like this 
[{"drivers":0,"next_DT":"May 18 2019  2:00AM"}]    

Expected 
[{"DRIVERS":0,"NEXT_DT":"May 18 2019 2:00AM"}]
```

Below is my POJOClass where I'm mapping the results of the native query

```
public class GetTrucksDueResultModel 
{

     private int DRIVERS;

     private String NEXT_DT;

public GetTrucksDueResultModel()
{

}

public GetTrucksDueResultModel(String NEXT_DT,int DRIVERS)
{
    this.NEXT_DT = NEXT_DT;
    this.DRIVERS = DRIVERS;
}
public int getDrivers() {
    return DRIVERS;
}

public void setDrivers(int dRIVERS) {
    DRIVERS = dRIVERS;
}

public String getNEXT_DT() {
    return NEXT_DT;
}

public void setNEXT_DT(String nEXT_DT) {
    NEXT_DT = nEXT_DT;
}

}
```

And my sqlMapping in the entity class looks like this

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="GetTrucksDueResultMapping",
                   classes={
                   @ConstructorResult(targetClass=GetTrucksDueResultModel.class,
                  columns={
                           @ColumnResult(name="NEXT_DT", type=String.class),
                           @ColumnResult(name="DRIVERS", type=int.class)
                        })
})
```

Below are the dependencies in my pom xml.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>jconn4</groupId> <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson uses the getters to serialize the state. That's why the JSON attributes are lower case.

If you want to use the attributes you have to configure Jackson like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JsonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {

        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
                super.configure(objectMapper);
                objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
                objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This setts the PropertyAccessor on the fields instead of the getters and setters.

Comment: I think I'm missing some dependencies. And should I place this code in a new file?

Comment: Yes like in my example. How does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: I just found that adding @JsonGetter("NEXT_DT") on top of getter also works. But I have many such fields can't put this anotation everywhere

Comment: I have updated the post with my pom xml. Please check if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You pom.xml looks ok. Why do you think that you are missing dependecies

Comment: I'm getting compilations when I create a new class and add your code there

Comment: Accepted. Can you please help me out with this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/61634886/10944013 its similar to this post. I've been struggling with this since 2 days @Simon Martinelli

Answer (score 0):

Adding @JsonGetter("NEXT_DT") and @JsonGetter("DRIVERS") anotations on top of respective getters worked for me. But not a good idea if you have many fields.