# jpa entitymanager - map query result into nested dto classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm using **jpa EntityManager with hibernate** in my java spring application. Suppose I have a user entity like below:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    ...
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address
}
```

And I have Custom user dto object for passing into client:

```
public class UserDTO {
    private Long id;
    private AddressDTO address;
    ...
}
```

And I have a UserRepository that exceute normal jpql query with **`EntityManager`** and **`Query`**.

Note, I need to have custom dto, because my dto has some fields that does not exist in entity and must be calculated in query. Now my question: **is there any way with EntityManager that map flat query result into my nested UserDTO?** In fact, I need to map result of address in AdressDTO inside UserDto and so on.

Note: I want to use jpql not native sql query.

Comment: You have to do this by using manual mapping see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection

Answer (score 0):

You can construct DTO right in JPQL.
Here is an example.

```
select new your.package.UserDTO(u.id, a.country, a.city, a.street)
from User u join u.address a
where ...
```

Such query returns `List<UserDTO>`.

Of course `UserDTO` has to have appropriate constructor:

```java
public UserDTO(Long id, String country, String city, String street){
   this.id = id;
   this.address = new AddressDTO(country, city, street);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way.

You really need to fetch User and then convert it to UserDTO.
Don't build DTO within your queries.

For that conversion you need Java Mapper. I prefer [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org) but there is a plenty of such tools (ModelMapper, Dozer etc).

MapStruct is smart enough to manage nested objects as well.

Comment: So, which model should be the respone type of repository method? My original question was how can I map result of query into dto? If I want to map with mapstruct or any other mapper, what should be format of mapper input data?

Comment: The mapper input data might be the getters of your entity (User)

Comment: The problem is that when we fetch the entity and then convert it to DTO, we select all columns which can leads to performance issues.