# Native query result not getting set correctly in projection class

Tags: jpa, native, jpql

I'm trying to put the result of a native query into a projection.
But the query result values do not seem to be set to the proper fields in the projection object.

My native query is something like this:

```
@Query(value = "select p.siteId,"
        + " sum(case when p.arrivalDate = :date then 1 else 0 end) as arrivalTotal "
        + " sum(case when p.departureDate = :date then 1 else 0 end) as departureTotal "
        + " from product p "
        + " where p.collectionSite = :siteId"
        + " and (p.arrivalDate = :date or p.departureDate = :date", nativeQuery = true)
List<DeliverySummary> getDeliverySummary(@Param("siteId") String siteId,
        @Param("date") String date);
```

My projection class is:

```
    public interface DeliverySummary {
        String getSiteId();
        String getArrivalTotal();
        String getDepartureTotal();
    }
```

The results would return like:

```
siteId = 5 (when actual is site1)
arrivalTotal = "site1" (when actual is 2)
departureTotal = 2 (when actual is 5)
```

I suspect the issue is because the fields in the projection object are not native fields of the table (and entity), which are sums.  Is there a way to set this correctly? TIA

Comment: have you tried also to add an alias to siteId (as siteId)?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes. also tried with other variable name and correspondingly the field name in the projection class. but still the field values are not being set to the expected fields.

Comment: That sounds very strange. And you are 100% sure that the query returns the correct values?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yup. The values are correct, but their variable assignments are not. But I found a solution that worked for me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use @SqlResultSetMapping with any existing @Entity class and just add the @SqlResultSetMapping snippets.  Thanks to @Edwin Dalorzo

Here's the solution I used: [JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection?rq=1) with @SqlResultSetMapping** section