# How to convert Integer param which can be 'null' to '0' when selecting data with Spring Data JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Assume we have entity **Animal**. There are animals in DB with '**amount**' = null, it's a valid case to save animal without the '**amount**'.
Is there a way to convert field '**amount**' to **0** in case it's **null** in query?

- The simplest workaround seems to convert amount null to '0' earlier
  when saving, but it's not allowed.
- As another workaround we can do    this mapping to '0' after fetching
  it from the repository. When sorting by amount in asc order, null values will be at the    beginning, in desc order they will be at the end. And after
  converting to '0' everything will be at the right place. But it seems that can cause problems with pagination in future

What is the proper way to do it in Query?

> Spring Data Jpa 2.2.9.RELEASE, Postgresql 42.2.16.

```
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<AnimalEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT animal FROM AnimalEntity animal" +
            " WHERE animal.ownerId = :ownerId" +
            " and function('replace', upper(animal.name), '.', ' ') like function('replace', upper(concat('%', :name,'%')), '.', ' ') "
    )
    Page<AnimalEntity> findAllLikeNameAndOwnerSorted(String ownerId, String name, Pageable pageable);

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "animal")
public class AnimalEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Integer amount;

    private String name;
    
    private String ownerId;

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also important to mention. The solution I suggested with replacing nulls with zero is incorrect, because of the different null ordering in Postgresql and HSQLDB.
But it will work in tests, if you're using HSQLDB.

```
Animal entities in DB test sample: [
Animal(name=Cat, amount=599999.99),
Animal(name=Dog, amount=null),
Animal(name=John, amount=5000)
]
 
Hsqldb amount desc query result:
[
Animal(name=Cat, amount=599999.99),
Animal(name=John, amount=5000),
Animal(name=Dog, amount=null)
]

Postgresql amount desc query result:
[
Animal(name=Dog, amount=null)
Animal(name=Cat, amount=599999.99),
Animal(name=John, amount=5000)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA supports the **COALESCE** function. Thus you can set up the desired value via this function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(amount,0) AS desiredAmount FROM AnimalEntity animal
```

The code should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "animal")
public class AnimalEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private Integer amount;

public AnimalEntity() {
}

public AnimalEntity(Integer amount, String name) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public Integer getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<AnimalEntity, Long> {

@Query(
        value = "SELECT animal.id AS id, COALESCE(animal.amount,0) AS amount, UPPER(animal.name) AS name FROM animal animal WHERE animal.name = :name",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<AnimalEntity> findAllLikeNameAndOwnerSorted(String name, Pageable pageable);


}
```

Also I have prepared the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class AnimalRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

@Test
void findAllLikeNameAndOwnerSorted() {
    AnimalEntity animalEntity = new AnimalEntity(null, "dog");
    animalRepository.save(animalEntity);
    AnimalEntity animalEntity2 = new AnimalEntity(1, "CAT");
    animalRepository.save(animalEntity2);
    System.out.println(animalEntity2.getId());

    Pageable sortedByName = PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("id"));
    Page<AnimalEntity> animals = animalRepository.findAllLikeNameAndOwnerSorted("dog", sortedByName);

    animals.forEach(System.out::println);
}

}
```

You can check the commit: https://gitlab.com/chlupnoha/meth/-/commit/76abbc67c33b2369231ee89e0946cffda0460ec9 - it is experiment project.

Comment: I know about this function. But I return paginated entities(AnimalEntity), not only their amount. I don't know how to apply 'coalesce' in that case

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection. You have to make the query a bit more verbose and select the properties of the mapped object.

Comment: Can you add the complete Query to answer? Which will be based on my existing Query and  AnimalEntity accordingly, including COALESCE in it

Comment: I just update the Answer. Unfortunately, you can not use a function keyword like this! It has to be part of the SELECT statement. I hope it is gonna help.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to preserve my functions. But it's necessary to change the syntax slightly.  The alternative to what I have in native query format is to add   **AND REPLACE(UPPER(animal.name), '.', ' ') LIKE REPLACE(UPPER(CONCAT('%', :name, '%')), '.', ' ')**